# How can I `await` on an Rx Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, ecmascript-2016

I'd like to be able to await on an observable, e.g.

```
const source = Rx.Observable.create(/* ... */)
//...
await source;
```

A naive attempt results in the await resolving immediately and not blocking execution

Edit:
The pseudocode for my full intended use case is:

```
if (condition) {
  await observable;
}
// a bunch of other code
```

I understand that I can move the other code into another separate function and pass it into the subscribe callback, but I'm hoping to be able to avoid that.

Comment: Can you not move the remaining code (which you want to wait for the source) into a `.subscribe()` method call?

Answer (score 224, accepted):

You have to pass a promise to `await`. Convert the observable's next event to a promise and await that.

```
if (condition) {
  await observable.first().toPromise();
}
```

*Edit note: This answer originally used .take(1) but was changed to use .first() which avoids the issue of the Promise never resolving if the stream ends before a value comes through.*

As of RxJS v8, `toPromise` will be removed. Instead, the above can be replaced with `await firstValueFrom(observable)`

Comment: Instead of take(1) could you use `await observable.first().toPromise();`?

Comment: @apricity That should come out the same.

Comment: @apricity If there were no values on completion, `first()` will result in rejection, and  `take(1)` will result in pending promise.

Comment: @estus: So, in general, it makes more sense to call `first()`, right?

Comment: @apricity @AgentME Actually you should NOT use either `take(1)` nor `first()`in cases like this. Since you are expecting exactly ONE event to happen you should use `single()` which will throw an exception if there is more than 1,while not throwing an exception when there is none. If there is more than one there is likely something wrong in your code / data model etc. If you do not use single you will end up arbitrarily picking the first item that returns without warning that there are more. You would have to take care in your predicate on upstream data source to always maintain the same order.

Comment: @ntziolis Note that .single() waits until the source stream ends before it even outputs the value and ends, which may not work well in all situations that .first() or .take(1) would work.

Comment: Don't forget the import: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';`

Comment: Now that toPromise() is deprecated, how should we do this?

Comment: @Jus10 I can't find anything to indicate `toPromise()` is deprecated. Where did you read that?

Comment: `import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';` now

Comment: @EstusFlask Actually `take(1)` will **not** yield a pending promise. It will yield a promise resolved with `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe it worked before, but now `pipe` is needed: `observable.pipe(first()).toPromise()`.

Comment: Use the new ` firstValueFrom()` or `lastValueFrom()` instead of toPromise. Available in RxJS 7+. See : https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/

Comment: I've used just `observable.toPromise()` many times without issue. If you really only need the first one, then use  `observable.first().toPromise()` - otherwise the plain implementation will take the *last value after completion*

Answer (score 76):

Use the new `firstValueFrom()` or `lastValueFrom()` instead of `toPromise()`, which as pointed out here, is deprecated starting in RxJS 7, and will be removed in RxJS 8.

```
import { firstValueFrom} from 'rxjs';
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

this.myProp = await firstValueFrom(myObservable$);
this.myProp = await lastValueFrom(myObservable$);
```

This is available in RxJS 7+

See: https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/

Answer (score 31):

It likely has to be

```
await observable.first().toPromise();
```

As it was noted in comments before, there is substantial difference between `take(1)` and `first()` operators when there is empty completed observable.

`Observable.empty().first().toPromise()` will result in rejection with [`EmptyError`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/util/EmptyError.js~EmptyError.html) that can be handled accordingly, because there really was no value.

And `Observable.empty().take(1).toPromise()` will result in resolution with `undefined` value.

Comment: Actually `take(1)` will **not** yield a pending promise. It will yield a promise resolved with `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, that's correct. I'm not sure why the post differed, possibly the behaviour changed at some point.

Answer (score 23):

**Edit:**

`.toPromise()` is now deprecated in RxJS 7 (source: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise)

**New answer:**

> As a replacement to the deprecated toPromise() method, you should use
> one of the two built in static conversion functions firstValueFrom or
> lastValueFrom.

Example:

```
import { interval, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
async function execute() {
  const source$ = interval(2000).pipe(take(10));
  const finalNumber = await lastValueFrom(source$);
  console.log(`The final number is ${finalNumber}`);
}
 
execute();
 
// Expected output:
// "The final number is 9"
```

---

**Old answer:**

If `toPromise` is deprecated for you, you can use `.pipe(take(1)).toPromise` but as you can see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/Observable.ts#L329-L343) it's not deprecated.

So please juste use `toPromise` (RxJs 6) as said:

```
//return basic observable
const sample = val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
//convert basic observable to promise
const example = sample('First Example')
  .toPromise()
  //output: 'First Example'
  .then(result => {
    console.log('From Promise:', result);
  });
```

async/await example:

```
//return basic observable
const sample = val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
//convert basic observable to promise
const example = await sample('First Example').toPromise()
// output: 'First Example'
console.log('From Promise:', result);
```

Read more [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html).

Comment: toPromise is deprecated, and it's has been removed in RxJS 8. The docs in your link is outdated.

Comment: what does Rx mean?

Answer (score 12):

You will need to `await` a promise, so you will want to use `toPromise()`.  See [this](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) for more details on `toPromise()`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `toPromise()` is not recommended as it is getting depreciated in RxJs 7 onwards. You can use two new operators present in RxJs 7 `lastValueFrom()` and `firstValueFrom()`. More details can be found [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated)

```
const result = await lastValueFrom(myObservable$);
```

Implementations in Beta version are available here:

- [firstValueFrom](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/firstValueFrom.ts)
- [lastValueFrom](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts)

Answer (score 0):

I am using RxJS V 6.4.0, hence I should use deprecated one in V 7.x.x `toPromise()`. Inspired by other answers, here is what I did with `toPromise()`

```js
import { first, ... } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

if (condition) {
  await observable$.pipe(first()).toPromise();
}

...
```

Note how I used `last()` inside a `pipe()`. Because on mine `observable.first()` does not works just like mentioned by [macil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1289657/macil)

Hope this helps others who using RxJS V 6.x.x as I do :).

Thanks.