# How to get content of Redux store in console without devtools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-devtools

With React Devtools installed, I can get store by:

```
$r.store.getState()
```

And how to do it without React Devtools?

Comment: Are you ok with checking it in the browser dev console?

Comment: Yes. I want to get store in browser dev console, but without changing source code (without attaching store to window, etc.)

Comment: For those wanting attach ngrx store (which has no `getState()`) to window for console debugging without DevTools, try `store.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(_store => (window as any)._store = _store)`. For similar ideas, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633684

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was in a situation where I could not assign anything to window and I also did not have the opportunity to use react or redux dev tools.

This is obviously undocumented and brittle but it seemed to work for me on a few different sites that had redux. Outputs access to state (store with minor tweaks) within console.

Assumes you are rendering react to a dom node with id `react-root`.

```
const appStates = []
const reactRoot = document.getElementById('react-root')
let base

try {
    base = reactRoot._reactRootContainer._internalRoot.current
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Could not get internal root information from reactRoot element')   
}

while (base) {
    try {
        state = base.pendingProps.store.getState()
        // This also sometimes works...
        // state = base.stateNode.store.getState()
        appStates.push(state)
    } catch (e) {
        // no state
    }
    base = base.child
}

console.log('Application States', appStates)
```

Comment: This is perfect answer. The solution which works without editing original application source code ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot, after two days I just found my solution.

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1**

You can attach the store to `window` while you're in a dev mode, and then you can access if from the console.

```
if(env === 'dev') { // only an example - you'll need to tailor this to your build system
    window.store = store;
}
```

Now you can access it directly from the console:

```
store.getState()
```

**Option 2 (in chrome)**

1. After store creation `console.log(store)`.
2. In console, right click the store, and select `Store as global variable`.
3. You'll get a new variable, by the name of `temp1` (or tempX if you've created others).
4. Now you can use `temp1.getState()`.

Don't forget to clear the console statement (usually done as part of the build).

Answer (score 4):

I guess the simplest way is to assign it to the global `window` just right after you created your store:

```
const myStore = createStore();

if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  window.store = myStore;
}
```

and later you can access it in browser console like:

```
store.getState();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly just before ReactDOM.render block.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to access the store is probably using Provider from the react-redux. When we pass the store to this component, it makes it available to all children down the element tree. Store is made available via React's context API.

So in a child component of Provider, we can now do something like

```
render() {
  const { store } = this.context;
  console.log(store)
  return(
  ...
  )
}
```

This is the same way that react-redux's connect HOC is able to access the store.

Also did you know there is a great [devtools chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) for Redux? This keeps a history of our state and actions so you can track the changes of your application lifecycle. This may be the best solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version in Typescript. I had to add the Redux store to the window object, but in an SPFx (Sharepoint Online) solution with Typescript. I added this code before the `return()` method in the App.tsx component, where I also imported the store and inserted it into the :

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../../../store/store";


export const App = (): ReactElement => {
  (window as Window & typeof globalThis & { store: any }).store = store;
  
return (...)
}
```

Then you can access the store in the Browser console by typing `window.store.getState()`