# is observable take from ngrx synchronous?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following function that:

Take a value from my store =>
Transform it to csv =>
Create a download link

```
  downloadCSV() {
    let href;
    this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedRoute).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((route) => {
      if (route) {
        const csv = this.csvManipulatorService.generateCSVFromJSON({filename: route.routeId, data: route.waypoints, columns : ['id', 'position', 'rotation']});
        href = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:text/csv,' + encodeURIComponent(csv));
      }
    });
    return href;
  }
```

(don't take care about the fact there is no guard, is simplified)

I thought the subscribe was not synchronous. But from this accepted answer:

[How to get current value of State object with @ngrx/store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633684/how-to-get-current-value-of-state-object-with-ngrx-store)

it looks like it is not.

My question is is this going to work 100% of the time? Is the subscribe with a take always synchronous ?

Comment: All observables (anything you can subscribe) should be considered not synchronous. But you can always convert an observable to promise and change your function to an async function. That's a solid approach if you need only one value as fast as possible (null or defined)

Comment: Side note: using the pipeable `select` operator is the preferred method since 6.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

**Two answers**

1. No. Subscribe with take is not always synchronous. What makes an observable async/sync is the *producer* of the emitted values, not the operators in the stream. Now, if you did not use `take(1)` or unsubscribe from the Observable at some point, it's not a synchronicity issue you would have, but a memory leak. The `take(1)` is important, but not because of synchronicity concerns.
2. In your case, you are using a function to create and subscribe to an observable that gets the latest data from the store, which is basically a [BehaviorSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject) in that it always returns the most recent values on subscribe, and then the updates after that. This is a *synchronous* action, and I see no reason why it wouldn't always work.

This is testable by creating a simple synchronous Observable, modifying a value, and then logging it out immediately.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ujs6u9

You could simplify this however and return the Observable itself instead of wrapping it in a function:

```
csvHref$ = this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedRoute).pipe(
  take(1),
  map(route => {
    if (!route) {
      return null;
    }

    const csv = this.csvManipulatorService.generateCSVFromJSON({
      filename: route.routeId,
      data: route.waypoints,
      columns : ['id', 'position', 'rotation']
    });

    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`data:text/csv,${encodeURIComponent(csv)}`);
  })
)
```

And then instead of calling it like a function, you just subscribe to it to get the value.

```
csvHref$.subscribe(href => doSomethingWithHref(href));
```

Based on your usage that may not be possible, but you should think of Observables as being functions already.

I recommend https://medium.com/@benlesh/learning-observable-by-building-observable-d5da57405d87 as a good read.

Comment: Your second point doesn't sound right. An observable being a Subject doesn't make subscribing and getting the first value a synchronous operation. That's not even true for ReplaySubject. It is true for BehaviorSubject, though.

Comment: Just another point: BehaviorSubject has an actually synchronous getValue method. If you want a sync value, you should just use that. If the library exposes it as an Observable rather than a BehaviorSubject, you'd be relying on an implementation detail anyway (which you shouldn't) rather than the contract.

Comment: @IngoBürk your point is correct about BehaviorSubject. However, ngrx circa 2.0 removed their `value` implementation. Instead they guarantee that the subscribing to the store will always synchronously return the current state.

Comment: OK, if the library explicitly states so, then it's also "OK" to rely on it. Still feels somewhat dirty and I'd avoid it if at all possible, though.

Comment: NgRx feels somewhat dirty.