# What is the difference between Promises and Observables?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-promise, angular-observable

What is the difference between `Promise` and `Observable` in Angular?

An example on each would be helpful in understanding both the cases. In what scenario can we use each case?

Comment: I would suggest you to read this post; [Angular2 promise vs observable](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-observables-http-separating-services-components/)

Comment: To anyone reading this Q&A - as someone who is involved in both worlds from a maintainer, speaker and long time user PoV I encourage you to read the official RxJS docs and the MDN documentation on promises. **I personally find the answers here entirely misleading and incorrect** and believe they are, while with good intentions from people trying to help, very harmful.

Comment: I would suggest you to read this angular official document https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables

Comment: a Promise is always asynchronous, while an Observable can be either synchronous or asynchronous, a Promise can provide a single value, whereas an Observable is a stream of values (from 0 to multiple values), you can apply RxJS operators to an Observable to get a new tailored stream

Answer (score 2049, accepted):

**Promise**

A `Promise` handles a **single event** when an async operation completes or fails.

Note: There are `Promise` libraries out there that support cancellation, but ES6 `Promise` doesn't so far.

**Observable**

An `Observable` is like a **`Stream`** (in many languages) and allows you to pass zero or more events where the callback is called for each event.

Often `Observable` is preferred over `Promise` because it provides the features of `Promise` and more. With `Observable` it doesn't matter if you want to handle 0, 1, or multiple events. You can utilize the same API in each case.

`Observable` also has the advantage over `Promise` to be **cancellable**. If the result of an HTTP request to a server or some other expensive async operation isn't needed anymore, the `Subscription` of an `Observable` allows you to cancel the subscription, while a `Promise` will eventually call the success or failed callback even when you don't need the notification or the result it provides anymore.

While a `Promise` starts immediately, an `Observable` only starts if you subscribe to it. This is why Observables are called lazy.

Observable provides **operators** like `map`, `forEach`, `reduce`, ... similar to an array

There are also powerful operators like `retry()`, or `replay()`, ... that are often quite handy.
[A list of operators shipped with rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators)

Lazy execution allows you to build up a chain of operators before the observable is executed by subscribing, to do a more declarative kind of programming.

Comment: So is there a good reason to use Promise instead of Observable in the  single callback case or should Observables also be used there since they can work that way too?  Basically, is it good practice to "Observable all the things" or does Promise still have its place?

Comment: If you want to use the reactive style, just use observables everywhere. If you have observables only you can easy compose. If you mix them it's not so clean anymore. If you don't care about reactive style, you can use promise for single events where you don't care about cancelable and observable for streams of events.

Comment: For a good intro resource on Observables/RxJs/Reactive Programming: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754 ("The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing")

Comment: @JoshWerts I was asking the same question about a week or two ago. Did a lot of research. As far as I am concerned there is just NOT a good reason to use Observables over Promises for http. None of the advantages are really relevant here in practice. With that said, now that I understand Observables, I am too lazy to write "toPromise()"

Comment: @VSO what are the arguments against `Observable`, or why do you think the arguments for `Observable` are not valid or not strong enough?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hey - I have no arguments against Observables or functional programming. I am simply stating that I believe that people running into Observables mainly via http in NG2 have no real reason whatsoever to use Observables over Promises to make the calls. They lose nothing practical by using promises. The debounce and retry operators are irrelevant - you can debounce with ng-debounce and if a call is expected to fail, generally, there is a problem with the code. The only time I needed to work with retrying calls was while querying unstable third-party APIs for HVT.

Comment: And just to stress this again - I completely agree with your explanation and you helped me a ton while I was starting out. I am just saying there is no significant value-added in THIS particular use case - your answer (and several others by you on the topic) are all great.

Comment: @VSO I agree that in the normal use cases there is not much difference. For more advanced scenarios it can make IMHO quite a difference. Also the `Http` API might change a bit over time and make better use of `Observables` . `Http` is still quite basic.

Comment: @VSO I also wouldn't say that using `toPromise` is a bad idea. Only if you are using `Observables` everywhere in a reative-like programming style, this really can show its potential. Thanks a lot for your feedback. I didn't perceive it as criticism. I'm just curious what you learned and perhaps can share something new to me.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Maybe you are right - this is just my opinion from working with Observable http calls in NG2 and tons of experience with standard promises in NG1. I also ended up taking 2 classes on RxJS since we last talked, so I feel like I have a good grip on what Observables provide.

Comment: @VSO I agree - I can see the advantages of Observable over Promise, but there are often times where there's a single callback and that's it.  In this case, I think Observable creates code that is a little harder to understand, so I just toPromise() in this case.  Mixing does hurt consistency a little.  Basically, no right/wrong answer IMO.

Comment: Re: promises not able to be cancelled. Is this just in angular 2? In angularJS, promises can be cancelled with a timeout parameter.

Comment: They can be made to complete with an error prematurely, but that doesn't cancel the operation.

Comment: Can anybody tell me, how the ability to cancel an `Observable` is an advantage over `Promises`? When using promises, I can chain them and control whether the next promise in the chain should be fired or not.

Comment: A `Promise` (ES6) can't be cancelled while waiting for an async call to complete, while Observable does. This cancellation might propagate back to the producer of the async result and might even stop an expensive calculation, while a `Promise` would still do the expensive calculation even when the receiver already decided to not not be interested in the result anymore and won't wait for it.

Comment: In scenarios where my api call returns a single thing (ie a JSON object or array of objects) I have found myself using a "hot" observable. 

`vendors: Observable<any> = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).publishLast().refCount();`

The cool thing about using Observable in this case is you can subscribe to it in multiple places and it won't requery.

Anyway, just one reason to use Observables.

Comment: But please don't forget that `Promise`, along with `async`/`await` makes your code flat again! In a majority of situations, and in projects that don't deal with rocket science, there is no need to write those horrible nested functions with unnecessarily complicated chains of methods. You can use `async`/`await` today with transpilers, like `TypeScript`, and write actual human-readable flat code without any of the `rxjs` boilerplate. You will probably still need `rxjs` sometimes in select situations, because it really does have a lot of things to offer.

Comment: This answer is misleading, an observable is _not_ like a stream it is like a _function that returns a stream_.

Comment: @evilkos in my experience, nesting when using rxjs happens only when doing it wrong. If done right you rarely need more than one level of indentation as the pipeline is a pretty powerful concept. Nesting mainly happens when you subscribe to everything instead of chaining observables.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer if only single value is returned `Promise` or `Observable` any one can be used. When stream of values being returned that's where `Observable` shine and also with some addition features it has with `retry()`, `forEach`, calcelable etc. I am bit newbie to this, so can you please provide an example where an api would return stream of values? Also any example where api request need to be canceled?

Comment: @Vivek "where api request need to be canceled" if you make an expensive request to a server and the user navigates away from the current route, you might want to cancel that request. "stream of values" a simple example would be a service that provides the `isLoggedIn` state. A component or service might want to get notified about changes. The component or service subscribes to an Observable and gets notified whenever the user logs in or out. Another example would be a progress bar component that gets passed an Observable the provides progress updates.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer "if you make an expensive request to a server and the user navigates away from the current route, you might want to cancel that request" how this request can be cancelled?

Comment: @Vivek store the subscription and unsubscribe to cancel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664741/easiest-way-to-unsubscribe-subscriptions-angular/42664776#42664776

Comment: @Vivek Or you can use takeUntil which I find cleaner and easier to use, but it depends on what framework you are using. In Angular you would use it in combination with ngOnDestroy for example.

Comment: cancelling a Promise is the wrong way to think about promises. The Promise's responsibility it only to record success or failure in an async compatible way. If you want to cancel an http request you cancel the request, not the promise, and make the result of cancelling either fulfill or reject the Promise. https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/ea0yhd4p/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I couldn't agree more. This is one of the most confusing parts of using Observables and I think it _really_ should be addressed here. The fact that subscribing to an Observable can have side effects (but doesn't always) is the main reason I don't like using them.

Comment: Copied content from - https://hype.codes/differences-between-promise-and-observable-angular

Comment: @PardeepJain thanks for pointing it out. I haven't found a way to leave a comment. I just enjoy that this answer has become so popular that some find it worth stealing :D

Comment: I started using Promise a few years ago and have got used to its pattern, but then it defaults to Observable in Angular.  it seems to make no difference to me as I have no need for the new features for the Observable. It is very handy though you can covert any return to Promise with the toPomise() function.

Comment: I always get stuck when they explain Observable as function that return a stream of data 
What exactly does stream of data mean 

Suppose i do a http call using observable in angular will the response be streamed

Answer (score 418):

Both `Promises` and `Observables` provide us with abstractions that help us deal with the **asynchronous** nature of our applications. The difference between them was pointed out clearly [by Günter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables/37365955#37365955) and @Relu.

Since a code snippet is worth a thousand words, let’s go through the below example to understand them easier.

> Thanks @Christoph Burgdorf for [the awesome article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html)

---

Angular uses Rx.js Observables instead of promises for dealing with HTTP.

Suppose that you are building a **search function** that should instantly show you results as you type. It sounds familiar, but there are a lot of challenges that come with that task.

- We don't want to hit the server endpoint every time user presses a key. It should flood them with a storm of [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) requests. Basically, we only want to hit it once the user has stopped typing instead of with every keystroke.
- Don’t hit the search endpoint with the **same query parameters** for subsequent requests.
- Deal with out-of-order responses. When we have multiple requests in-flight at the same time we must account for cases where they come back in unexpected order. Imagine we first type **computer**, stop, a request goes out, we type **car**, stop, a request goes out. Now we have two requests in-flight. Unfortunately, the request that carries the results for **computer** comes back after the request that carries the results for **car**.

The demo will simply consist of two files: `app.ts` and `wikipedia-service.ts`. In a real world scenario, we would most likely split things further up, though.

---

Below is a **Promise-based** implementation that doesn’t handle any of the described edge cases.

`wikipedia-service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { URLSearchParams, Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class WikipediaService {
  constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {}

  search (term: string) {
    var search = new URLSearchParams()
    search.set('action', 'opensearch');
    search.set('search', term);
    search.set('format', 'json');
    return this.jsonp
                .get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK', { search })
                .toPromise()
                .then((response) => response.json()[1]);
  }
}
```

We are injecting the `Jsonp` service to make a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request against the **Wikipedia API** with a given search term. Notice that we call `toPromise` in order to get from an `Observable<Response>` to a `Promise<Response>`. Eventually end up with a `Promise<Array<string>>` as the return type of our search method.

`app.ts`

```js
// check the plnkr for the full list of imports
import {...} from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Wikipedia Search</h2>
      <input #term type="text" (keyup)="search(term.value)">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Array<string>;

  constructor(private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {}

  search(term) {
    this.wikipediaService.search(term)
                         .then(items => this.items = items);
  }
}
```

There is not much of a surprise here either. We inject our `WikipediaService` and expose its functionality via a search method to the template. The template simply binds to **keyup** and calls `search(term.value)`.

We unwrap the result of the **Promise** that the search method of the WikipediaService returns and expose it as a simple array of strings to the template so that we can have `*ngFor` loop through it and build up a list for us.

See the example of **Promise-based** implementation on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8ap1Lm?p=preview)

---

Where **Observables** really shine

Let’s change our code to not hammer the endpoint with every keystroke, but instead only send a request when the user stopped typing for **400 ms**

To unveil such super powers, we first need to get an `Observable<string>` that carries the search term that the user types in. Instead of manually binding to the keyup event, we can take advantage of Angular’s `formControl` directive. To use this directive, we first need to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` into our application module.

`app.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, JsonpModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Once imported, we can use formControl from within our template and set it to the name "term".

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="term"/>
```

In our component, we create an instance of `FormControl` from `@angular/form` and expose it as a field under the name term on our component.

Behind the scenes, **term** automatically exposes an `Observable<string>` as property `valueChanges` that we can subscribe to. Now that we have an `Observable<string>`, overcoming the user input is as easy as calling `debounceTime(400)` on our `Observable`. This will return a new `Observable<string>` that will only emit a new value when there haven’t been coming new values for 400 ms.

```js
export class App {
  items: Array<string>;
  term = new FormControl();
  constructor(private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {
    this.term.valueChanges
              .debounceTime(400)        // wait for 400 ms pause in events
              .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
              .subscribe(term => this.wikipediaService.search(term).then(items => this.items = items));
  }
}
```

It would be a waste of resources to send out another request for a search term that our application already shows the results for.  All we have to do to achieve the desired behavior is to call the `distinctUntilChanged` operator right after we called `debounceTime(400)`

See the example of **Observable** implementation on [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/SIltBL/)

> For dealing with out-of-order responses, please check the full article
> http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

As far as I am using HTTP in Angular, I agree that in the normal use cases there is not much difference when using Observable over Promise. None of the advantages are really relevant here in practice. I hope I can see some advanced use case in the future :)

---

> Learn more
>
> - https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/
> - https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#observables

Comment: I don't completely buy the decision of turning Http service into Observable based. Every explanation I hear relies on the same example: The search by term. But that one is about handling browser events. I would like to hear what the advantage is in applying it when dealing with asynchronous http requests.

Comment: Was the decision accidental to avoid mixed patterns?

Comment: @AlexPollan, there's actually a good explanation for benefits of the http service returning an observable on this podcast with Ben Lesh: https://devchat.tv/js-jabber/jsj-248-reactive-programming-and-rxjs-with-ben-lesh.

Ultimately, the major benefit is that you can cancel an observable, and a use case for this described in the link above - while a little contrived - is that if you call out to multiple apis and only care about the first response, no matter which of the apis you called gets back to you first, you can then cancel the requests to the others.

Comment: @nikolasleblanc, Im pretty sure you can use $q.race() for that?

Comment: Both of your Plunker projects are broken. Looks like it couldn't find some resources.

'Failed to load resources: the server returned with a status of 404 ()'
https://npmcdn.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.5//bundles/platform-browser.umd.js

Comment: doesn't `valueChanges` trigger only when value is changed? so whats the usage of `.distinctUntilChanged()` ?

Comment: Consider you type foo, stop, type another o, followed by an immediate backspace and rest back at foo. That should be just one request with the term foo and not two even if we technically stopped twice after we had foo in the search box. That's what distinctUntilChanged did. You can check more example from https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html

Comment: @AlexPollan, The advantage is that an Observable-based HTTP service makes it easy to cancel mid-flight HTTP requests. The race condition in trungk18's answer can be solved by simply unsubscribing from the HTTP observable prior to making a subsequent request. RXJS switchMap can be used for HTTP requests triggered by another observable (e.g. valueChanges). For standalone HTTP observables, you can unsubscribe and re-subscribe manually.

Comment: Who is "Relu"? What answer or comment does it refer to?

Comment: @nikolasleblanc I suppose when you call multiple api you send multiple requests, and you just take into account the first. What's the point at cancelling requests ? When requests are gone, you cannot catch them back. I just take the first response and ignore the others. const myData = await Promise.Any( [ callApi1, callApi2... ] ); What need of observables in this ?

Answer (score 326):

Both **Promises** and **Observables** will help us work with the **asynchronous functionalities** in JavaScript. They are very similar in many cases, however, there are still some differences between the two , Promises are values that will resolve in `asynchronous` ways like HTTP calls. On the other hand, Observables deal with a sequence of **asynchronous events**. The main differences between them are listed below:

**Promise:**

- having one pipeline
- usually only use with async data return
- not easy to cancel

**Observable:**

- are cancellable
- are re-triable by nature such as retry and retryWhen
- stream data in multiple pipelines
- having array-like operations like map, filter etc
- can be created from other sources like events
- they are functions, which could be subscribed later on

Also, I've created the graphical image for you below to show the differences visually:

[image: Promises and Observables image]

Comment: promise "not easy to cancel" , is it possible to cancel them ?

Comment: yes, there is a way to cancel them as well... some people use bluebird or third party libraries...  also using Q library in Angular there are ways to cancel it... but as I said not very handy

Comment: Having one pipeline sometimes has advantange, ex. in APP_INITIALIZER, if you have multiple pipeline it can never finish sometimes or finish multiple times.

Comment: running across this issue APP_INITILIZER code I inherited uses observable it is not very clear or usable, I just need to fetch some configuration from a web service it's a one off fail or success event clearly tailored for Promises. Is there an easy way to make it behave like a Promisse... what I mean is the 'then' behavior, since the results cascade heavily on the return of each other.

Comment: cancelling a `Promise` is the wrong way to think about how promises. The `Promise`'s responsibility it only to handle success or failure in an async compatible way.. If you want to cancel an http request you cancel the request, not the promise, and make the result of cancelling either fulfil or reject the Promise. https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/ea0yhd4p/

Comment: @gman Exactly. The Promise simply represents some future _value_. It does _not_ represent the _operation which generates the value_. You cannot cancel a value. You cannot retry a value. It's just a value. It may or may not be _present_ yet, and it may _never_ exist because an exception occurred, but that's it.

Comment: @gman has explained Promise basis quite well. I think people wrongly suppose that Promises should do something that they are not intended for, Actually, they are very good at doing what they are supposed to do.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that it's not easy to cancel a promise and that cancelling a Promise is the wrong way to think about them. You just have to pass a cancelableToken that will tell you process to stop at some execution points. const longCalcPromise = callLongCalculation( ...params, cancelToken);  cancelToken.cancel();  The good practice is make the promise fail upon cancelation and return a cancelation error.

Answer (score 122):

There is one downside of Observables missing in the answers. Promises allow to use the ES7 async/await functions. With them you can write asynchronous code like it would be a synchronous function call, so you don't need callbacks anymore. The only possibility for Observables to do this, is to convert them to Promises. But when you convert them to Promises, you can only have one return value again:

```
async function getData(){
    const data = await observable.first().toPromise();
    //do stuff with 'data' (no callback function needed)
}
```

Further reading: [How can I `await` on an Rx Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190375/how-can-i-await-on-an-rx-observable)

Comment: Also surprised why no one pointed out this killer perk of Promises - simplicity and transparency thanks to async/await. I switched to Promises just for the ability of writing flat code. Simple business logic and UI interaction code shouldn't look like rocket science and be polluted by the nested hell of reactive extensions. Also, async/await is not only in the future, you can use it in public production apps now using transpilers. I use TypeScript 2.3 and it's awesome, like a real language.

Comment: Nice, but thinking in a reactive way and all with the RxOperators maybe this is not a killer feature

Comment: I use Promise async/await all the time and it is really powerful. It provides code familiarity and clarity while using a true async javascript engine. In contrast, Observables are synchronous, they are executed in the main Execution stack while Promise async/await use js asynchronous features in engine: event loop, libuv, microtasks queue etc. Making Observables asynchronous by using setTimeout() is silly because it is a resource hog and you cannot control the order of execution in the event-loop. It uses the WebAPI part of the event loop, while the events in the microtask queue have priority

Comment: This answer should definitely get more votes. Observables are powerful, and with great power comes great complexity and callback-hell/callback-pyramid-of-doom type of code. Use Observables in places where you need some of their advanced features. Stick to async/await with Promises for simple cases, and your code will be 10x easier to understand.

Comment: +1 It looks to me like the `async/await` weren't commonly available when many of the top answers were written. Back then there `Observable`s were `Promise`s on steriods so there was a benefit to exclusively use `Observable`s. Now using both is better because you don't end up in callback-hell.

Comment: the trouble with async/await is people forget to add the try/catch/finally which is a red flag IMO. If you do add the try/catch/finally, your code is usually more verbose and less flexible than simply composing observables.

Answer (score 92):

**Promises**

1. Definition: Helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions), but **only once** when executed.
2. Not lazy
3. Not cancellable (there are Promise libraries out there that support cancellation, but ES6 Promise doesn't so far). The two possible decisions are

   - Reject
   - Resolve
4. Cannot be **retried** (Promises should have access to the original function that returned the promise to have a retry capability, which is a bad practice)

**Observables**

1. Definition: Helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values in a continuous sequence (**multiple times**) when executed.
2. By default, it is *lazy* as it emits values when time progresses.
3. Has a lot of operators which simplifies the coding effort.
4. One operator **retry** can be used to retry whenever needed, also if we need to retry the observable based on some conditions **retryWhen** can be used.

**Note**: A list of operators along with their interactive diagrams is available here at [**RxMarbles.com](http://rxmarbles.com/)**

Answer (score 55):

Promises and Observables both handle the asynchronous call only.

Here are the differences between them:

**Observable**

1. Emits multiple values over a period of time
2. Is not called until we subscribe to the Observable
3. Can be canceled by using the unsubscribe() method
4. Provides the map, forEach, filter, reduce, retry, and retryWhen operators

**Promise**

1. Emits only a single value at a time
2. Calls the services without .then and .catch
3. Cannot be canceled
4. Does not provide any operators

Comment: What exactly do you mean by promise emits only single value, while observable emits multiple

Comment: A promise does not emit a value at all - a promise _is_ a value over time. A promise multicasts that value to multiple subscribers - once you hold the promise you already have a value. An observable is like a _function_, subscribing to it invokes the action.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Still I didn't get the mean of multiple subscribers can you please provide a  link or example. Thanks

Comment: observable1.subscribe(subscriber1), observable1.subscribe(subscriber2) - this invokes the _function_ multiple times.

Comment: @sudheernunna please update the image. Did you copy paste from kudvenkat videos? And grammar is also not proper in the text in image.

Answer (score 44):

Let's say you want to go to the beach. You have to make a decision based on weather. You have three ways:

1. You look outside and see the raindrops, so you change your mind. This is a synchronous operation. You stopped what you were doing, went to check the outside, got the result and then got back to what you were doing.
2. You ask your brother who is next to you to check the weather conditions for today. While he is checking the weather, you still keep doing what you were doing. This is an async operation. You gave a task to your brother and waiting for the promise resolved. In this case, you are getting one response and after you get your response, you no longer get any update.
3. This time, you turn on a radio and listening to a weather channel that broadcasts weather conditions 24/7. In this scenario, instead of getting one single response, the response is ongoing. This response is like a `subscription` to an `observable`. the observable is the "weather" and the subscription is the "radio signals that keep you updated". As long as your radio is on, you are getting every available update. You are not missing any information until you turn off the radio. When you turn off the radio, it means "you unsubscribed".

Answer (score 39):

I have summarized the differences below,

**Observable:**

1. Observable is just a **`function`** that takes **`an observer`** and returns a **`function Observer: an object with next, error.`**
2. Observer allows you to **`subscribe/unsubscribe`** to its data stream, emit
   next value to the observer, **`notify`** the observer about **`errors`** and
   inform the observer about the **`stream completion`**
3. Observer provides a **`function to handle next value`**, errors and
   end of stream ([UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) events, http responses, data with web sockets).
4. Works with **`multiple values`** over time
5. It is **`cancel-able/retry-able`** and supports operators such as **`map, filter, reduce`**, etc.
6. Creating an Observable can be
   -**`Observable.create()`** - returns Observable that can invoke methods on
   -**`Observer  Observable.from()`** - converts an array or iterable into
   -**`Observable  Observable.fromEvent()`** - converts an event into Observable
   -**`Observable.fromPromise()`** - converts a Promise into Observable
   -**`Observable.range()`** - returns a sequence of integers in the specified range

**Promise**:

1. A promise represents a task that will finish in the future;
2. Promises become **`resolved by a value`**;
3. Promises get rejected by exceptions;
4. Not **`cancellable`** and it returns **`a single value`**
5. A promise expose a function **`(then)`**

   -then returns a new **`promise`**;

   -allows for the **`attachment`** of that will be executed based on
   **`state`**;

   -**`handlers`** are **`guaranteed`** to execute in **`order attached`**;

Answer (score 27):

I believe all the other answers should clear your doubts.
Nevertheless, I just wanted to add that observables are based on functional programming, and I find very useful the functions that come with it like map, flatmap, reduce, zip. The consistency the web achieves especially when it depends on API requests is a brutal improvement.

I strongly recommend [this documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html), since it's the official documentation of reactiveX and I find it to be the most clear out there.

If you want to get into observables, I would suggest this 3-part post:
http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1/

Although it's meant for RxJava, the concepts are the same, and it's really well explained. In reactiveX documentation, you have the equivalences for each function. You must look for RxJS.

Answer (score 27):

### Overview:

- Both Promises and Observables help us dealing with asynchronous operations. They can call certain callbacks when these asynchronous operations are done.
- A Promise can only handle one event, Observables are for streams of events over time
- Promises can't be cancelled once they are pending
- Data Observables emit can be transformed using operators

You can always use an observable for dealing with asynchronous behaviour since an observable has the all functionality which a promise offers (+ extra). However, sometimes this extra functionality that Observables offer is not needed. Then it would be extra overhead to import a library for it to use them.

### When to use Promises:

Use promises when you have a  **single** async operation of which you want to process the result. For example:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // do something once, possibly async
  // code inside the Promise constructor callback is getting executed synchronously

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});

//after the promise is resolved or rejected we can call .then or .catch method on it

promise.then((val) => console.log(val))      // logs the resolve argument
       .catch((val) => console.log(val));    // logs the reject argument
```

So a promise executes some code where it either resolves or rejects. If either resolve or reject is called the promise goes from a **pending state** to either a **resolved** or **rejected** state. When the promise state is resolved the `then()` method is called. When the promise state is rejected, the `catch()` method is called.

### When to use Observables:

Use Observables when there is a **stream (of data) over time** which you need to be handled. A stream is a sequence of data elements which are being made available **over time**. Examples of streams are:

1. User events, e.g. click, or keyup events. The user generates events (data) over time.
2. Websockets, after the client makes a WebSocket connection to the server it pushes data over time.

In the Observable itself is specified when the **next event** happened, when an **error occurs**, or when the Observable is **completed**. Then we can subscribe to this observable, which activates it and in this subscription, we can pass in 3 callbacks (don't always have to pass in all). One callback to be executed for success, one callback for error, and one callback for completion. For example:

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
  // create a single value and complete
  observer.onNext(1);
  observer.onCompleted();
});

source.subscribe(
  x => console.log('onNext: %s', x),   //  success callback
  e => console.log('onError: %s', e),  //  error callback
  () => console.log('onCompleted')     //  completion callback
 );

// first we log: onNext: 1
//  then we log: onCompleted
```

When creating an observable it requires a callback function which supplies an observer as an argument. On this observer, you then can call `onNext`, `onCompleted`, `onError`. Then when the Observable is subscribed to it will call the corresponding callbacks passed into the subscription.

Answer (score 26):

I've just dealt with an issue where Promises were the best solution, and I'm sharing it here for anyone stumbling across this question in the event it's useful (this was exactly the answer I was looking for earlier):

In an Angular2 project I have a service that takes some parameters and returns a value list to populate drop down menus on a form. When the form component initializes, I need to call the same service multiple times with different parameters to define a number of different dropdown menus, however if I simply queue up all the variables to call the service, only the last one succeeds and the rest error out. The service fetching from the database could only handle one request at a time.

The only way to successfully populate all the dropdown menu variables was to call the service in a way that prevented a new request from being processed until the last request was finished, and the Promise / .then mechanism solved the problem nicely.

```js
  fetchValueList(listCode): Promise<any> {
      return this.dataSvc.getValueList(listCode, this.stateSvc.currentContext, this.stateSvc.currentLanguageCode)
          .map(response => response.json())
          .toPromise();
  }

  initializeDropDowns() {
      this.fetchValueList('First-Val-List')
          .then(data => {
              this.firstValList = data;
              return this.fetchValueList('Second-Val-List')
          }).then(data => {
              this.secondValList = data;
              return this.fetchValueList('Third-Val-List')
          }).then(data => {
              this.thirdValList = data;
          })  }
```

I defined the functions in the component, and then called initializeDropDowns() in ngOnInit.

The fetchValueList function returns a Promise, so the first call passes the first listCode and when the Promise resolves, the return value is in the data variable in the .then block where we can assign it to the this.firstValList variable. As the function has returned data, we know the service has finished and it's safe to call again with the second listCode, the return value is in the data variable in the next .then block and we assign it to the this.secondValList variable.

We can chain this as many times as required to populate all the variables, and on the last code block we simply omit the return statement and the block terminates.

This is a very specific use case where we have a single service that needs to be called multiple times as the component initializes, and where the service has to complete its fetch and return a value before it can be called again, but in this case, the Promise / .then method was ideal.

Comment: This is certainly also possible with (higher-order) observables. You could for instance use `scan()` to build a stream of sequential observables. However, your approach is maybe more explicit and easier to understand.

Comment: You could replace "then" with "switchMap" and do the exact same thing w/observables.

Comment: The problem with switchMap, as I understand it, is that it will start all the requests in parallel and wait until they all return, then return the values to the calling function whereas in my situation, I have a single server that I can't call multiple times in parallel (as the server will drop unfinished requests when new ones come in), so I had to make sure each call to the database service completed before starting a new call, and the Promise/then seemed to be the best and perhaps only way to solve that.

Comment: Why didn't you use chained mergeMap? As far as I understood your code, this one is pretty simple and does the job as good as your example.  @StephenR.Smith

Comment: @Ore Can you add a code example of that solving the same problem as another answer? Would be a good reference and may be a good refactoring opportunity in the future. The requirement is that whatever code can't call the backend service in parallel, it has to call, wait for the return value and call again.

Comment: May I point out how much easier to read this would be with `async`/`await`?
`async initializeDropDowns() {
 this.firstValList = await this.fetchValueList('First-Val-List');
 this.secondValList = await this.fetchValueList('Second-Val-List');
 this.thirdValList = await this.fetchValueList('Third-Val-List');
}`

Comment: Using `async`/`await` here is a great example of Promises being cleaner and easier to read that Observables. Though I would really look into why that backend service cannot handle multiple concurrent calls. What about when a user has two tabs open to your page? Or if you have two users...

Comment: @YonaAppletree Each tab gets its own session, so multiple users don't have an issue, but multiple calls to the same service with different parameters at the same time causes issues. I have no control over the server side, so I'm having to deal with the limitations of the services as provided. Your async/await example is similarly clean to the chained promise approach, I think either works just as well.

Answer (score 25):

#### Promise:

- Provide a single future value;
- Not lazy;
- Not cancellable;

#### Observable:

- Emits multiple values over time;
- Lazy;
- Cancellable;
- Supports map, filter, reduce and similar operators

#### You can use promises instead of observables when calling HTTP in Angular if you wish.

Answer (score 21):

### **Promise vs Observable similarity first**

1. Both are used to handle async code.
2. Please look for the promise example. The promise constructor passes a resolve reference function which will get called when it gets called with some value upon completion of some async task.

   ```
   const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       resolve("Hello from a Promise!");
     }, 2000);
   });

   promise.then(value => console.log(value));
   ```
3. Observable example now. Here we also pass a function to observable - an observer to handle the async task. Unlike resolve in the promise, it has the following method and subscribes in place of then.
4. So both handles async tasks. Now let's see the difference.

   ```
   const observable = new Observable(observer => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       observer.next('Hello from a Observable!');
     }, 2000);
   });

   observable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
   ```

---

### **Promise vs Observable difference**

**Promise**

1. It resolves or reject a single value and can handle a single value async task at a time.
2. A promise once resolved the async value it completes, can no longer be used.its just one-time use and here it falls short.
3. Not cancellable
4. No rxjs support for operators.

**Observable**

1. ability to emit multiple asynchronous values.
2. Used to handle the stream of events or values. Consider you have an array of numerous tasks or values, and you want every time value is inserted into this it should be handled automatically. Anytime you push a value into this array, all of its subscribers will receive the latest value automatically.
3. Observables are useful for observing input changes, repeated interval, broadcast values to all child components, web socket push notifications, etc.
4. Can be cancelled using unsubscribe method anytime.
5. One more last good part that promise that has is support for rxjs operators. You have many pipe operators majorly map, filter, switchMap, combineLatest, etc. to transform observable data before subscribing.

   [image]

Answer (score 18):

Promise - Provides a single future value. Not lazy. Not cancel-able. It will either reject or resolve.

Observable - Provides multiple future values. Lazy. Cancel-able. It provides other methods, like *map*, *filter*, and *reduce*.

Answer (score 16):

*Promise emits a single value while Observable emits multiple values. So, while handling a HTTP request, Promise can manage a single response for the same request, but what if there are multiple responses to the same request, then we have to use Observable. Yes, Observable can handle multiple responses for the same request.*

**Promise**

```
const promise = new Promise((data) =>
{ data(1);
  data(2);
  data(3); })
.then(element => console.log(‘Promise ‘ + element));
```

**Output**

```
Promise 1
```

**Observable**

```
const observable = new Observable((data) => {
data.next(1);
data.next(2);
data.next(3);
}).subscribe(element => console.log('Observable ' + element));
```

**Output**

```
Observable 1
Observable 2
Observable 3
```

Answer (score 14):

**Short answer:**

**Observable** is ***better***. It has all **Promises** features plus extra features.

---

**Long answer:**

**Promises:**

- One time use "Return data once"
- No cancel
- One listener
- No socket support

**Observables:**

- Return data many times as data change
- Support cancel
- Support socket
- Support many listeners and notify them when data change
- Support map, filter, and reduce

Comment: I don't think you can say Observables are objectively better. There are number of downsides to Observables noted in the various answers here. The ones that stand out to me are Observable's complexity, and that they don't work directly with await/async. I personally find them really hard to work with because you cannot determine the behavior of an Observable when using it -- you have to look at the code that generated it. Whereas with a Promise, you know exactly how they work, always. For example, sometimes subscribing to an Observable has side effects (e.g. an http request), but sometimes not.

Comment: For angular, it depend on your case.
for most cases we will work with services and some data which will affect different places, sockets, cancellation, map, filter and reduce. so it will be better on those cases as promises not supporting them. so again it depend on your case

Answer (score 11):

**A Promise emits a single event when an async activity finishes or fails.**

An Observable is like a Stream (in many languages) and permits to pass at least zero or more events where the callback is required for every event.

Frequently Observable is preferred over Promise since it gives the highlights of Promise and more. With Observable it doesn't matter if you need to handle 0, 1, or various events. You can use the similar API for each case.

**Promise:** 
promise emits a single value

**For example:**

```
const numberPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(5);
    resolve(10);
});

numberPromise.then(value => console.log(value));
// still prints only 5
```

**Observable:** 
Emits multiple values over a period of time

**For example:**

```
  const numberObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
        observer.next(5);
        observer.next(10);
    });

numberObservable.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
// prints 5 and 10
```

we can think of an observable like a stream which emits multiple values over a period of time and the same callback function is called for each item emitted so with an observable we can use the same API to handled asynchronous data. whether that data is transmitted as a single value or multiple values over some stretch of time.

**Promise:**

- A promise is Not Lazy
- A Promise cannot be cancelled

**Observable:**

- Observable is Lazy. The "Observable" is slow. It isn't called until
  we are subscribed to it.
- An Observable can be cancelled by using the unsubscribe() method
- An addition Observable provides many powerful operators like map,
  foreach, filter, reduce, retry, retryWhen etc.

[Angular Promises vs Observables](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Angular-Promises-vs-Observables/)

Answer (score 8):

1. A Promise is eager, whereas an Observable is lazy.
2. A Promise is always asynchronous, while an Observable can be either
   synchronous or asynchronous.
3. A Promise can provide a single value, whereas an Observable is a
   stream of values (from 0 to multiple values).
4. You can apply RxJS operators to an Observable to get a new tailored
   stream.

Answer (score 7):

Something I ran into that wasn't apparent from a first reading of the tutorial and documentation was the idea of multicasting.

Make sure you're aware that by default, multiple subscriptions will trigger multiple executions in an Observable.   Multiple subscriptions to a single HTTP call Observable will trigger multiple identical HTTP calls unless you `.share()` (enable multicasting).

A promise forces you to deal with one thing at a time, unwrap its data, handle exceptions, has language support for cool things like async/await, and is pretty bare-bones otherwise.

An Observable has lots of bells and whistles, but you need to understand the power you're working with or it can be misused.

Answer (score 7):

**Promise:**

An Async Event Handler - The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

**Syntax:** new Promise(executor);

**For example:**

```
var promise_eg = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve('foo');
  }, 300);
});

promise_eg.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "foo"
});

console.log(promise_eg);
```

[image]

**About Promise:**

It has one pipeline, so it will return values only once when it’s called.
It’s a one-way handler, so once called you may not able to cancel.
Useful syntax you can play around, **when()** and **then()**.

**Observables:**

Observables are lazy collections of multiple values over time. It’s really a great approach for async operations. It can be done with [rxjs](http://reactivex.io/) which has cross-platform support, can be used with Angular/React, etc.

It acts like stream liner and can be multi pipeline.
So once defined, you can subscribe to get return results in many places.

**Syntax:** `import * as Rx from "@reactivex/rxjs";`
to init:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, "click"),
Rx.Subject()
```

etc.

To subscribe: `RxLogger.getInstance();`

**For example:**

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

range(1, 200).pipe(
  filter(x => x % 2 === 1),
  map(x => x + x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Since it supports multi pipeline, you can subscribe to the result in a different location,

[image]

It has many more possibilities than promises.

**Usage:**

It has more possibilities, like *map*, *filter*, *pipe*, *map*, *concatMap*, etc.

Answer (score 7):

> Both Promises and Observables help us dealing with asynchronous
> operations. They can call certain callbacks when these asynchronous
> operations are done.
>
> Angular uses Observables which is from RxJS instead of promises for dealing with HTTP

`Below are some important differences in promises & Observables.`

[image: difference between Promises and Observables]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual content as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> Below are some important differences in promises & Observables.

**Promise**

- Emits a single value only
- Not cancellable
- Not sharable
- Always asynchronous

**Observable**

- Emits multiple values
- Executes only when it is called or someone is subscribing
- Can be cancellable
- Can be shared and subscribed that shared value by multiple subscribers. And all the subscribers will execute at a single point of time.
- possibly asynchronous

For better understanding refer to the https://stackblitz.com/edit/observable-vs-promises

Answer (score 5):

I see a lot of people using the argument that Observable are "cancellable" but it is rather trivial to make Promise "cancellable"

```js
function cancellablePromise(body) {
  let resolve, reject;
  const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res; reject = rej;
    body(resolve, reject)
  })
  promise.resolve = resolve;
  promise.reject = reject;
  return promise
}

// Example 1: Reject a promise prematurely
const p1 = cancellablePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('10', 100))
})

p1.then(value => alert(value)).catch(err => console.error(err))
p1.reject(new Error('denied')) // expect an error in the console

// Example: Resolve a promise prematurely
const p2 = cancellablePromise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('blop'), 100)
})

p2.then(value => alert(value)).catch(err => console.error(err))
p2.resolve(200) // expect an alert with 200
```

Answer (score 5):

**Promise**: is an ES6 feature that deals with async code which executes immediately on the creation that can only emit a single value at the time and are not cancelable. With modern applications and the complexity of the functionality needs, it will be necessary to implement complex code, if in the case we are dealing to execute many promises at the same time, or filter before execution or make some transformation:

```
myPromise.then((resolvedValue) => {
    console.log(resolvedValue);
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**Observable:** is an Object provided by the Rxjs library that helps us to work with reactive programming in JavaScript applications, which provides chaining and subscription to handle complex applications having the advantage to be cancelable, providing many values at the same time. In addition, we can benefit from applying chaining of other operators like **`retry()`**, **`map()`**, **`filter()`**, **`switchMap()`**, etc. which helps to deal with complex use cases and heavy user interfaces.

**Example instant search:**

```
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.searchEntries(term))
    );
  }
```

**Example many APIS calls in parallel:**

```
let character = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    let characterHomeworld = this.http.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    );

    forkJoin([character, characterHomeworld]).subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('result °', results[0]);
      console.log('result 1', results[1]);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

One more difference: **Global vs. Imported**

Promise is a [standard built-in object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and you can use it directly. [Check the browser support here](https://caniuse.com/promises).

```js
const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('ready with out any installation');
  }, 300);
});

myPromise
.then(value => { console.log(value) })
.catch(err => { console.log(err) });
```

Observable, [Reactive Extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) for JavaScript need [RxJS installation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/installation) & [import](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) before use

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 4):

While the [Günter Zöchbauer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables/37365955#37365955) is good in general, I don't think it emphasises that when dealing with Angular Components you almost always want to use an Observable because it supports cancellation. Promises cannot be cancelled and will resolve even if your component is destroyed. Angular tends to be forgiving until it's not.

For example, any manual change detection on a destroyed component will cause an exception:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Promise API
  this.service.getData().then(d => {
     this.data = d;
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  });

  // Observable API
  this.service.getData().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((d) => {
     this.data = d;
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  });
}
```

If your component is destroyed before the promise is resolved, you'll get an `attempt to use destroyed view` error when the promise is resolved.

Alternatively, if you use observables with the [takeUntil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription/41177163#41177163) pattern, then as soon as your component is destroyed the subscription will be cancelled.

This is a bit of a contrived example, but executing code for a component that is destroyed is probably going to lead to bugs.

Answer (score 4):

1. Promises are focused only for single values or resolves. Observables are stream of data.
2. Observables can be canceled, but promises can't be canceled.

The least known one, at least to me is:

3. Promises are always of asynchronous nature, but observables can be both synchronous and asynchronous.

If you want to read about it in detail, I wrote a blog post following on this answer - *[The 4 differences between Observables and Promises in JavaScript](https://vikky.dev/observables-vs-promises)*

Answer (score 4):

A Promise is always asynchronous, while an Observable can be either synchronous or asynchronous.
Observables return data many times as data change.
Promise emits a single value.
Observables are lazy collections of multiple values over time. It’s really a great approach for async operations.
Promises are not lazy.
Observables can be cancelled using unsubscribe().
Promises cannot be cancelled.

Answer (score 3):

A Promise handles a single event when an async operation completes or fails.

Promises are auto-executed in the application, while observables are lazy. So we have to subscribe to observables to return the data.

We cannot unsubscribe promises. They will execute every time in contrast to Observables that can be unsubscribed.

Answer (score 2):

**I like to criticize using `Observables` for `API calls`:**

I don't want to come across as overly critical, but I've had some lingering questions about the use of `Observables` in `HTTP/API calls` in `Angular`, `React` etc. While I like `Observables` and appreciate their flexibility, I wonder whether they are always the right choice, especially when it comes to `plain HTTP calls`?

You may notice that `Promises` are suitable only for `one-time calls`, while `Observables` can keep streams open indefinitely. I understand the value of open-ended streams, but in my experience, `one-time HTTP calls` make up a significant majority of use cases in most business applications. As it stands, If I have to use `Angular` I often find myself using `Observables` in a way that essentially mimics `Promises`.

**I see the potential for `Observables` in handling event streams, such as click events and data streams, and I acknowledge their value in these contexts. However, when it comes to `HTTP/API calls` it feels like we're trying to fit the 90% use case into the 10% use case with this approach.**

I'm not against exploring alternative technologies, but I wonder if the shift toward `Observables` is worth the complexity of it! particularly when it comes to HTTP calls. Perhaps it would make more sense to offer a lean, `Promise-based HTTP` solution for the majority of use cases while encouraging those with genuine streaming needs to use `RxJs` directly.

From my perspective, `Promises` are ideal for `simple, one-time asynchronous operations` that resolve to a single value. `Observables`, in contrast, seem to be engineered for handling intricate data streams, with **features like lazy evaluation, cancellation, and advanced transformation and composition of emitted values.**

**In conclusion, my view is that the choice between `Promises` and `Observables` for `HTTP API calls` would be `Promises` 90 percent of the time.**

**UPDATE: Swagger/OpenAPI Client Code Generators**

Due to the intrinsic nature of `Promises`, it's easy to retrieve responses from `async` functions with the `await` keyword. Considering the fact that not everything or every feature in `JavaScript` is `Observable-friendly`, this can raise serious problems with features that are already adapted with `Promises` but not with `Observables`.
for example, there are great tools like **[openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/)** that work very well with generators that use `Promises`. The most important thing in working `swagger/openAPI client code generators` is using `access_token` in a way that to be injected into the generated codes, and getting `access_token` in a secure way **(not in browser storage! Please don't do that!)** from the server session is most of the time `Promise` like. **you can always find a way to adapt a getAccessToken function that returns Promise to the generated codes, but with generated/created Observable codes it's painful.**

Answer (score 1):

Observables and Promises are helping us to work with the asynchronous functionalities in JavaScript/TypeScript. They are very similar in many cases, however, there are still some differences between them.

[image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: Except that not code but plain info, so i think it's okay to post it as an image

Answer (score 0):

Promise and Observable are both used in Angular(typescript) to handle asynchronous data, but they differ in their usage and their behavior.

- Promise :

  - Is a one-time event(resolve/reject)
  - Returns a single value(resolved or rejected once time)
  - Handle a single asynchronous event
  - No canceling and no socket

**expample of uses cases : Error handling and recovery/Handling sequential operations/Inter-component communication**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

fetchData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get('https://api.examplepromise.com/data')
     .toPromise()
     .then(data => resolve(data))
     .catch(error => reject(error));
 });
}
```

- Observables:

  - Stream of values that can emit multiple values over time
  - Can be Subscribed and can emit values as long as the stream is active.
  - Handle multiple asynchronous events
  - Can be canceling and support socket/mapreducer(ngrx) operations
    **expample of uses cases : Monitoring changes in input elements/Animations and transitions/Centralized state management with RxJS/Debouncing user input to limit API calls**

> Blockquote

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  listenToButtonClicks() {
  fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click')
  .subscribe(event => console.log(event));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Differences between `Promise` and `Observable`

|  | Promise | Observable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| How many events can receive | Exactly 1 event or error, which also means that 'stream' completed and there won't be new events or errors | 0 or more events, 0 or 1 error and 1 completion event, which we can listen and react to even if there weren't events or errors |
| Completion | Happens once after first event or error | Happens once after `error(err)` or `complete()` is called, firing regular event via `next(event)` doesn't complete `Observable` |
| Cancellation support | Doesn't support running task cancellation, can't cancel requests in progress represented with pure `Promise` | Supports running task cancellation, can cancel requests in progress represented by `Observable` |
| When starts listening events | Immediately after `Promise` is created | After `subscribe` is called, we are not required to create `Observable` only when we are ready to start listening event |
| Does store last values? | Always stores 1 last value/error | Depending on implementation and operators used. Most `Observable`-s don't store last values, but we can create observable which store `n` last values via operators like `shareReplay(1)` |
| Has analogues in other languages? | No, `Promise`-s in other languages have differences, like `Task` in C# has cancellation support | Yes, like https://github.com/dotnet/reactive in C#, or https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava in Java |
| Supports easy async/await syntax? | Yes | No |
| Supports specifying schedulers on which to do computations? | No, but it is not that difficult to wrap calls which notify `Promise` in `schedule` | Provides scheduler support via operators or overloads https://rxjs.dev/guide/scheduler#scheduler-types |

Answer (score 0):

After going through all the answers to this question, there's a risk that readers may conclude Observables are superior to Promises, and thus, should be used in every case, even when dealing with single-value returns. The assumption that Observables have rendered Promises obsolete, and therefore, should be the rule of thumb, can often lead to convoluted code, or what I call 'Trash code'. I will try to dispel such misconceptions and [complement Gunter's insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365955/3433751).

The Angular Team's recommendation to favor Observables over Promises in their documentation has, unfortunately, caused considerable misinterpretation, leading to severe disarray in the realm of front-end web applications.

Consider a small front-end web application. Here, the observable, sourced from an HTTP get, is utilized directly in your template with a `|async` operator. It's straightforward, and the subscribe action is managed by the `|async` operator. However, in this instance, there's no data transformation or call for other async functions. While this scenario is common in demo apps, it's rarely the case in large front-end web applications.

Observables from the RxJS library are tailored for handling streams and events, not single-value asynchronous operations. Overusing Observables for all async operations introduces unnecessary complexity, cluttering your code with stream operators like map, filter, reduce, switchMap, mergeMap, and concatMap when they are entirely irrelevant.

Conversely, Promises, since Typescript 1.7, are compatible with async/await operators (even before Angular 2). With Promises, we can eliminate callback chains and nesting, thereby evading the notorious 'pyramid of doom'.

Observable-returning functions' signatures do not provide any indication as to whether they will return a single or multiple events. However, when a Promise is used for an async single-value operation, *the return type assures that it will yield one single value*, or an error. Usage of a correctly typed function is more predictable, and prevents the need to add documentation to specify the operation will return one single value.

This [Angular documentation article](https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables#observables-compared-to-arrays) demonstrates how Observables are akin to arrays. Now, picture a scenario where you decide to replace single values with arrays throughout your app: `Array<bool>` instead of `bool`, `Array<string>` instead of `string`, etc. This replacement eradicates the simple `if` usage, and you must now resort to `filter`. To modify an object, you'll need the `map` operator. How about adding two numbers? Well, you use the lodash `zipWith` operator off course:

```js
let quantity1 = [1];
let quantity2 = [2];
let total = zipWith(quantity1, quantity2, (a, b) => a + b);
console.log(total); // [3]
```

Such a scenario may seem absurd, but well documented in Angular and some youtube videos, some developers would be ok with it and say "it is the way", "Arrays are better because it can handle multiple value of different types with polymorphism".

In a strongly typed world, maintaining strict types for objects leads to code that's more understandable and maintainable.

Consider a service function that calls multiple APIs:

```js
  /**
   * Searching for the localization of a client file
   *
   * @remark This function does not comply with the specification of the ILocalizationSearchService interface
   * as no errors are raised in case of an exception.
   */
  public abstract getFileLocalization( countryName: string, clientName: string, fileNumber: number, fileName: string ): Observable<string>;
```

To get the file localization, the Angular Service has to sequentially call
external APIs. Localization is obtained from a folder, which comes from a box, which is derived from the client, which is ultimately obtained from the country.

When using Observable versions, you have two options: you can use the subscribe function, which is fundamental in the Observer pattern:
[image]

or use RxJS operators that handle the subscribe function and exception propagation for you:
[image]

The subscribe version leads to a pyramid of doom due to the number of nested callbacks. An alternative is to use RxJS operator version, which requires the use of the 'switchMap' operator. But the question arises, why 'switchMap' and not 'concatMap' or 'mergeMap'? The differences between these operators only matter when dealing with streams. So isn't it preferable to eliminate this question by using async/await operators? Here's the Promise version:

```js
  async getFileLocalization(countryName: string, clientName: string, boxNumber: number, folderName: string): Promise<string> {
    // Searching for the country
    let country = await this.proSer.FindCountry(countryName);

    // Getting the client
    let client = await this.proSer.GetClient(country, clientName);

    // Searching for the box
    let box = await this.proSer.FindBox(client, boxNumber);

    // Searching for the file
    let folder = await this.proSer.FindFile(box, folderName);

    // Getting localization
    return await this.proSer.GetLocalisation(folder);
  }
```

The complete code for this can be found on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-53hmru

**Cancellation with Promises**

Promises in Angular Apps may try to access properties of a component or an instance that may have been destroyed in the meantime. This can lead to memory leaks if the component is destroyed. There are two common ways to handle this:

1. Use a cancellation token ([like in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation)): pass a cancellation token as a parameter
   to the promise. If the instance is prone to destruction, trigger a
   rejection of the promise, or throw an exception with an async
   function.

   ```js
   async getStuff( stuffId: number, cancellation: CancellationToken ) {
       const stuff = await this.stuffService.getStuff( stuffId );

       if( cancellation.IsCancelled )
           throw 'cancelled';

       this.stuff = stuff;
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cancellation.cancel();
   }
   ```
2. Transform your async function/promise to an observable using **from**.
   The observable will be used solely for unsubscribing, with the only
   streaming operator used being 'takeUntil'.

   ```js
   getStuff( stuffId: number ) {
       from( this.stuffService.getStuff( stuffId ) ).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(stuff => {
           this.stuff = stuff;
         });
   }

     ngOnDestroy() {
       this.destroy$.next();
       this.destroy$.complete();
     }
   ```

Observables are best suited for processing streams of events such as user actions, peripheral events (like a Bluetooth connection or GPS positioning), or server events (like server-sent events or WebSocket pushes).

In summary, understanding when to use Observables and Promises is crucial. Replacing Promises with Observables may lead to unnecessary complexity and reduce maintainability

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of answers on this topic already so I wouldn't add a redundant one.

But to someone who just started learning **Observable** / **Angular** and wonders which one to use compare with **Promise**, I would recommend you keep everything Observable and convert all existing Promises in your project to Observable.

Simply because the Angular framework itself and its community are all using Observable. So it would be beneficial when you integrate framework services or third-party modules and chaining everything together.

---

Of course, no opinion is 100% correct in all cases, but at least I think 98% of the time for regular commercial projects implemented in Angular framework, Observable is the right way to go.

Even if you don't like it at the starting point of your simple hobby project, you'll soon realise almost all components you interact with in Angular, and most of the Angular-friendly third-party frameworks are using Observables, and then you'll end up constantly converting your Promise to Observable in order to communicate with them.

Those components includes, but are not limited to: HttpClient, Form builder, Angular material modules/dialogs, Ngrx store/effects and ngx-bootstrap.

In fact, the only Promise from the Angular ecosystem I dealt with in the past two years was `APP_INITIALIZER`.