# How to explain RxJS Subject to someone with Angular 1.X background

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

according to the official docs, I can use a Subject like this:
[docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)

However, I find it a rather theoretical explanation.

I have a strong background in Angular 1.X.

Can someone describe me, the concept 'subject' by comparing it with something in  Angular 1.X?

Comment: I don't think it's comparable with something AngularJS had. It's new, I would recommend reading the introduction on the website. http://reactivex.io/intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**$q.defer()** comes very close.
To clarify, 2 equal pieces of code.

```
//written with $q.defer()
function doWorkAsync() {
   var defer;
   defer = $q.defer();
   getStuff().then(function() {
       defer.resolve('finished here');
   }
   return defer.promise;
}
...
doWorkAsync().then(showResults);
```

```
//written with subject()
function doWorkAsync() : Observable<string> {
   let subject$ = new AsyncSubject<string>();

   getStuff().then(function() {
       subject$.next('finished here');
       subject$.complete();
   }
   return subject$;
}
...
doWorkAsync().subscribe(showResults);
```

To Summarize:

> defer.promise ~= observable. 
>  
>   defer.resolve && defer.reject ~=
>   observer.

Answer (score 1):

Subjects, in a way, are like **messengers**.

A kingdom dispatches messages to the messenger to notify its allies about an attack at its border. The allies tell the messenger that they will send forces to help out.

To come back to a more technical language:

Subjects are **two-way variables**. You can `subscribe` to it to receive updates when it changes, and change the variable by calling `next` on it and passing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found this explanation quite nice:

> An observable is like an array where the elements arrive delayed in time.

You can use operators like `.forEach()`, and `.map()` (and others).

It also has similarities to `Promise` but can emit 0 or more values on `subscribe()` (similar to `then()` but only calls the callback passed to `then()` once, while the callback passed to `subscribe()` can be called multiple times before the emitter resolves the observable).

See also [Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable/37365955#37365955)