# Angular 2 http get using Asp.net Core MVC

Tags: angular

I'm wondering how to get data in Angular 2 and put it in javascript. I've looked at the hero's tutorial and here's what I've come up with so far.

1. I've created a service with http var in constructor
2. I've created a function in the service to get articles

   ```
   GetArticles(subverse : string) : Observable<Article[]>
   {
      console.log("GetArticles URL: " + this._getArticlesUrl + "/?subverse="+subverse);

      return this.http.get(this._getArticlesUrl + "/?subverse="+subverse)
               .map(this.extractData)
               .catch(this.handleError);
   }

   private extractData(res: Response) 
   {
      let body = res.json();
      return body.data || { };
   }

   private handleError (error: Response | any) 
   {
      // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
      let errMsg: string;
      if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
      } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
      }
      console.error(errMsg);
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
   }
   ```

However, I don't understand what an observable is and why I have to use it here?

Now, this code actually calls my URL and the URL actually returns the article data as Json

URL response:

```
[{"id":1,"userID":"00d85571-e2d3-4817-8698-6aa1b184112b","title":"title","link":"http://google.com","text":"text","subverse":"home","votes":0,"isanon":false}]
```

Here is my Article class:

```
export class Article {
  id : number; 
  isanon : boolean; 
  title: string;
  link: string;
  text: string; 
  subverse : string;
  userID : string;  
  votes: number;
}
```

My question is, how do I get this URL response into an Article[] in my javascript? I've tried

```
  articlesO : Observable<Article[]>; 
  articles : Article[]; 

  this.articlesO = this.service.GetArticles(this.subverseStr); 

  this.articlesO.forEach(a => this.articles = a);
```

But my `this.articles` stays `undefined` in the code. How am I supposed to read the URL json and turn it into my `Articles[]`?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An observable is like a promise but like a stream version of it. You can find detailed information on promises vs observables here: [Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable)

And for your problem you need to **subscribe** to the observable in order to fire it.

Like this:

```
this.service.GetArticles(this.subverseStr).subscribe( (data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    //do something with the returned data.
    this.articles = data;
});
```

Comment: @ClaySmith What does the server return to you in the network tab of chrome?

Comment: I got it to work by deleting body.data from the json code. Server returns URL response in my original post. I think it's working! Thank you so much for quick response. :)

Comment: @ClaySmith Ah no problem, glad you figured it out :)