# Why does the http service return observables instead of promises

Tags: angular

I'm curious about the reasoning or discussion that lead to the angular 2 `http` service returning an observable instead of a promise for the response. I would understand the logic for something like a web socket connection or long-polling request, but the `http` service simply creates an `XMLHttpRequest`, and in the `load` event handler for the request, emits the response on the response observable and then completes the observable. Since this only returns one value, it seems to me like a promise would make more sense.

Edit:
I am aware of the difference between observables and promises, and know that you can convert observables to promises and vice versa. My question is more about the reasoning behind the decision to return an observable instead of a promise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - promise vs observable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable)

Comment: You can fall back to promises https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#promises Just put the .toPromise() method after your call

Comment: The question is why it isn't declared as a Promise or a Future if it behaves like one.

Answer (score 5):

I think the main reason was that observables can be cancelled.

See also [Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable).

Comment: As i know, Http request is single event. But Angular make it as a `Observable` because the advantage of `Observable` over `Promise` that is **cancelable**. Is that right?

Comment: That's what I believe and what my answer says.