# Is it better to use callback or promise in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, callback, promise

How want to call a webservice using `http.get` on Angular 2 handle the result and response to my caller with the result.

Is it better to use callback or promise ?

Thanks!! I use to work in NodeJS and often use callbacks.

Comment: Use `Observable.subscribe()` https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NodeJS we do a Callback but in Angular 2 it's better to use Promise or Observable.

Check this post to choose between Promise and Observable: [Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable)

Comment: How coool!! How can I tackle Observables?