# How could be return type of List of json object in Angular 2 typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new for angular2. Here,how could be the return type of getLeftData() what could be the specific return type?

HTTPTestService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService {
    private siteUrl="https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites";
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    getLeftData(): Promise<Items[]> {
        return this._http.get(this.siteUrl).
        toPromise()
        .then(response =>response.json().data as Items[])
    } 
}
```

json data:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "aliases": [
        "http://www.xyz.in",
        "http://facebook.xyz.in"
      ],
      "styling": {
        "tag_background_color": "#E0EAF1",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#3E6D8E",
        "link_color": "#0077CC"
      },
      "related_sites": [
        {
          "relation": "meta",
          "api_site_parameter": "meta.xyz",
          "site_url": "http://met.xyz.in"
        },
        {
          "relation": "chat",
          "name": "Stack Overflow Chat"
        }
      ],
      "markdown_extensions": [
        "Prettify"
      ],
      "launch_date": 1221436800,
      "closed_beta_date": 1217462400,
      "site_state": "normal",
      "favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/xyz/img/favicon.ico",
      "name": "Stack Overflow",
      "site_type": "main_site"
    }
  ]
}
```

if anyone help, How could be return type of List of json object in Angular 2 typescript?

Comment: You should use observables instead of promise. Check this   SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what's your exact problem, but let's try..

First: You should "model" your `Items`-class!

Second: You should use `json().items` instead of `json().data`!

Maybe this will help: https://plnkr.co/edit/gdwI1XfsUDCgZgoaKjce?p=preview

```js
export class ItemModel {
  aliases: string[];
  styling: {
    tag_background_color: string,
    tag_foreground_color: string,
    link_color: string
  },
  related_sites: {
    relation: string,
    api_site_parameter: string,
    site_url: string,
    name: string
  }[],
  markdown_extensions: string[],
  launch_date: number,
  closed_beta_date: number,
  site_state: string,
  // ...
  // ...
  name: string,
  // ...
  // ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <p *ngFor="let item of _items">{{ item.name }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  private _items: ItemModel[] = [];

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getLeftData().subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
      this._items = items;
    });
  }

  public getLeftData(): Observable<ItemModel[]> {
    return this._http
      .get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites')
      .map(response => response.json().items);
  }
}
```