# How to load multiple data via service and wait for it in Angular2

Tags: sqlite, angular, typescript, ionic2, resolver

I use Ionic 2 with Angular 2 in my project. In the root component you can click a "Add" button to add a new Report via a complex form and a lot of preprovided data (there are some selects that are feeded with data fetched from sqlite database)
Now in my "CreateReportComponent" i have the following constructor to load the data and assign it to local array variable:

```
selectEmployeeOptions: Employee[];

constructor(private dbService: DatabaseService) {
  dbService.getAllEmployees().then(employees => {
      this.selectEmployeeOptions = employees;
  });

  // load more data like tasks etc.
});
```

But when I want to modify this data in my component, the array is empty. I tried to do it in ngOnInit() but this seems to be to early as well.

I want to to something like this, before the component gets displayed:

```
  dbService.getAllEmployees().then(employees => {
      this.selectEmployeeOptions = employees;

      // modify data
      this.selectEmployeeTitleOptions = employees.map((item) => {
         return item.title;
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectEmployeeTitleOptions)) // --> empty
  });
```

But selectEmployeeTitleOptions is empty...

The function in the **databaseService** looks like this:

```
getAllEmployees(): Promise<Emplyoee[]> {
  let query = "SELECT * FROM employees";
  let employeeList = [];
  this.database.executeSql(query, []).then((data) => {
     if(data.rows.length > 0) {
       let e = new Employee();
       e.id = data.rows.item(i).id;
       e.firstname = data.rows.item(i).firstname;
       e.lastname = data.rows.item(i).lastname;
       employeeList.push(e);
     }
  }, (error) => {
     // handle error
  });
  return Promise.resolve(employeeList);
}
```

I read that there is the Resolve pattern (https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) But I need to make multiple calls and not only for contacts as in the example.

So the question: How to wait for multiple calls to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think something go wrong here

```
getAllEmployees(): Promise<Emplyoee[]> {
  let query = "SELECT * FROM employees";
  let employeeList = [];
  this.database.executeSql(query, []).then((data) => {
     if(data.rows.length > 0) {
       let e = new Employee();
       e.id = data.rows.item(i).id;
       e.firstname = data.rows.item(i).firstname;
       e.lastname = data.rows.item(i).lastname;
       employeeList.push(e);
     }
  }, (error) => {
     // handle error
  });
  return Promise.resolve(employeeList);
}
```

first `return Promise.resolve(employeeList);` will return empty array, because it is async process.
you need loop through data.rows, then format return data like this.

```
getAllEmployees(): Promise<Employee[]> {
  let query = "SELECT * FROM employees";
  return this.database.executeSql(query, []).then((data) => {
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = ; i < data.rows.length; ++i) {
      let emp = data.rows.item(i);
      let e = new Employee();
      e.id = emp.id;
      e.firstname = emp.firstname;
      e.lastname = emp.lastname;
      arr.push(e);
    }
    return arr;
  });
}
```

note that [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) return a promise object.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but get an error: TypeError: data.rows.map is not a function

Comment: could you provide `data.rows` value (log to console)?

Comment: Sure. **data.rows** is {"length":3} whereas **data** is {"rows":{"length":3},"rowsAffected":0}

Comment: how to loop through all rows

Comment: capture screen then upload to somewhere

Comment: The only way to get the array items it the one of my example. by calling data.rows.item(i)...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is forkJoin method that returns Observable that you should switch to instead of using Promises, for reference about why you should do this check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-2-promise-vs-observable).

Short information about fork join from its GitHub page:

> Runs all observable sequences in parallel and collect their last elements.

This way you can safely make parallel requests to your API.

For more information regarding forkJoin go [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md).

Additionally you should call services using ngOnInit as you mentioned before. For more information about Angular 2 lifecycle hooks see the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Comment: I will try to go with the answer of @tiep-phan. But I'll make use of your last advice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promise.all
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

You push all promises to an array, and then go

```
    let foo : [Promise<Emplyoee[]>,Promise<void>] = [getAllEmployees(), method2()];
    Promise.all(foo).then((results:any[]) => {
       let employeearray: any = results[0];
       /* and on an on */
     });
```