# How to send an objecto using HTTP Post in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rest, http

Im trying to send an object called Pack to my API Rest server from my angular service. In order to do so, I have the following function:

```
save_pack(Pack: any){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      this.http
        .post("http://localhost:8000/save_pack",Pack)
        .subscribe(res => {
            resolve(res);
          },
          (err: any) => {
            reject(err);
          }
        )
    });
  }
}
```

However, I know that the way im trying to send Pack is not correct. I would like to know how can I send Pack correctly so I can get it in my API Rest and then how can I access that object receive. I know that when you use GET, you can do:

```
const Pack = req.query.Pack;
```

How can I do the same with POST?

My API Rest POST calling is:

```
app.post('/save_pack', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const Pack = req.body.Pack;
    console.log("Paquete: " + Pack);

    let result = await save_pack(Pack);
    res.send(result)
    return res;

})
```

Comment: Does this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741499/6444705

Comment: I don´t see how that user is sending the object and then gets it.

Comment: Why you're suing Promise instead of Observable?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest is to use Observable insteaf of Promise :

```
      save_pack(pack: any){
            this.httpClient.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/save_pack', pack)
 .subscribe(result => {
  console.log('result saved with success');
   }, err => {
  console.log('err saving new pack', pack);
    
   });
              
          }
        }
```

For the back-end, you can get the body data :

```
const pack = req.body.pack;
```

My suggestion for you to implement a clean code : (always give a type for your data instead of type any )

Comment: Why do you add + '\choice' to the URL?

Comment: I just edited and correct it, please check it , if it works , please upvote :)

Comment: There is an error when I try to do req.body.pack, saying that it is undefined

Comment: Try to make console.log for req.body and what' s the  result you got

Comment: Just says undefined

Comment: can you share your back-end code please !

Comment: What's the result of console.log(req.body) ? you can eliminate  const Pack = req.body.Pack;
    console.log("Paquete: " + Pack); temporarily until we debug your body result

Comment: As I have said, i get undefined.

Comment: Did you added app.use(express.bodyParser()) to your express code ? you need to test your API via postman, I tried to help with Angular , but the back-end I think it's not implemented correctly

Comment: You mean adding this ? app.use(express.bodyParser()) right before app.get and app.post functions right?

Comment: Yeah ,it should be added

Comment: No, still getting the same error. I don´t know what else I can do

Comment: If you can put your project in public gihub repo, that I can show the code and find a solution :)