# How to return data coming from response instead of subscription json in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, php, angular

My Service :

```
fetchData(url,request)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+url,request).subscribe(
        (response) => {return response.json()}
    );
  }
```

My Component :

```
ngOnInit()
    {
        this.response = this.dataService.fetchData('friends/grow_network',{});
        console.log('s ',this.response);
    }
```

if I console response.json() in service it shows proper data which is coming from api but if I console in component it shows like this :

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null…}
```

how to get data in component which is coming from api not Subscriber data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing it your way, you write in the variable "reponse" the observable object and not the result. The value of the result is not there yet when calling the method, because it will be asynchronous.

To get what you want you have to do the following:

```
fetchData(url,request)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+url,request).map(
        (response) => {return response.json()}
    );
  }

ngOnInit()
    {
        this.response = this.dataService.fetchData('friends/grow_network',{})
                         .subscribe(result => {
                           this.response = result;
                           console.log('s ',this.response);
                         });

    }
```

Comment: thanks mate its working fine :)
I've one more question can we use javascript variable defined in our component or service ?

Comment: no problem got it I can use window[variable_name] thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can using  [Observables](https://web.archive.org/web/20190521133222/https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/using_observables.html)  in angular . and please checkout this below discussion

[What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-promise-vs-observable)

---

Now try this below code instead of your code in component

```
 this.response = this.dataService.fetchData ('friends/grow_network'{})
                 .subscribe(res=> { console.log(res);
                 }), error => alert(error);
```

and you service code should be

```
fetchData(url,request)
  {
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl+url,request).map(
        (response) => {return response.json()}
    );
  }
```