# Difference between observables and promises in AngularJS.

Tags: angularjs, angular

Difference between observables and promises in AngularJS?
What are the changes with respect to promises and observables in angular 2 and angular 4 versions?
Examples that explain this scenario would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promise can handle only a single async task wheras observable can handle multiple of them with more features.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365955/4185234) answer.

Comment: Instead of answering and linking to an answer, mark question as duplicate instead....