# Typescript Resolve Observable to Entity

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to resolve an observable to it's underlying type.  Yes, I am aware I should **NOT** be doing so, but at the moment I would like to test something without Fixing My architecture, and I would like to know if its possible.

This is a function in the base provider to call a GET request

```
getByRoute(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => <T>res.json());
}
```

I had an only class returning a concrete object with just an Id on it.
    //public currentUser = { id: 1 };

But now I'm trying to implement my provider to lazy load the current user,  I don't have time right now to switch everything to use an observable, but I would like to know my other code works.

```
private _user: User;
get currentUser(): User {
    if (this._user == null) {
        this._user = this.getLoggedInUser();
    }
    return this._user;
}
set currentUser(user: User) {
    this._user = user;
}

constructor(public usersProvider: Users) {
}

getLoggedInUser(): User {
    return this.usersProvider.getByRoute(URL).single();
};
```

How can I Resolve my Observable to get the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to the observable and then assign it to the property on your class.

```
this.usersProvider.getByRoute(URL).subscribe(next => {
  this.currentUser = next;
});
```

Note that you will need to handle cleanup of this subscription on your own! (this thread will help with that: [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription))

Also, you can't really "resolve" an Observable -- it is not a Promise! Check out this thread for more on that: [Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-promise-vs-observable)

Comment: Yes, but how will subscribing help? If someone requests current user in my code it will return before the request comes back

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, I'll ask a new question since this resolve most of mine