# Angular 5 : Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, mean

I got this error message "[ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable'.", how to solve it?

This is my Component :

```
  getUsers(){
    this.authService.getUsers().then((res) => {
      this.user = res;
      console.log(this.user);
    },(err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

This is my Service :

```
 getUsers(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://192.168.100.6:3000/users/data-tracer', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call `then` on a `Promise` object, so because your service returns an `Obaservable` object, you need to transform into a `Promise` with the `toPromise()` method and use `catch` method to manage error in this way:

```
getUsers(){
    this.authService.getUsers()
    .toPromise()
    .then((res) => {
      this.user = res;
      console.log(this.user);
    })
    .catch(err=> { console.log(err) });
  }
```

Here you can see a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-promise-observable-example).
That's all.

Comment: why I got "[ts] Argument expression expected." in .catch(err=> { console.log(err) }); ?

Comment: @Fatih. sorry, I had forgotten a parenthesis before `.catch`

Comment: If you need I put a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-promise-observable-example) on stackbliz

Answer (score 4):

"then" is a promise concept, RxJS is a bit different. If you want to sequence multiple calls, then you need to use forkJoin.
If you just want to have a success handler, then use subscribe and catch.

```
getUsers(){
    this.authService.getUsers().subscribe((res) => {
      this.user = res;
      console.log(this.user);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Make sure you understand the difference between promise and observable ([Angular - Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-promise-vs-observable)) and make appropriate design decision.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using `toPromise()` function like this:

```
  getUsers(){
    this.authService.getUsers().toPromise().then((res) => {
      this.user = res;
      console.log(this.user);
    },(err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

this.yourService.getWhatYouWant()
.map(data => {
  // do some thing
})
.toPromise()
.catch(err => {
  // handle error
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For use **toPromise().then()**, first is necesary to get the **Object of Observable** 
I use this solution:

```
   import { of } from "rxjs";
----------------

 var clienteDocument = this.clienteCollection.doc(nuevocliente.cli_cedula);
    var clienteObservable = clienteDocument.valueChanges(); //Get Observable<Object> from Firebase
    var cliente = of(clienteObservable); //Obtengo el Objeto de Observable
    cliente.toPromise().then((cliente) => {  
      if (cliente == null) {
        //cliente not existe

      } else {
        //cliente exist :)

      }
    });
```