# Angular 6: Module not found error regarding RxJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

**I am using**

- Angular CLI: 6.0.5
- Node: 8.11.1
- Angular: 6.0.3
- rxjs: 6.2.0

when Compiling the Angular 6 app I got errors, below is just the first one

```
ERROR in ./src/app/web.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise' in 
'C:\Node\ang\frontend\src\app'
```

My **web.service.ts** code

```
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class WebService{
    constructor(private http:Http){

    }
    getMessages(){
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:2000/messages").toPromise(); 
    }
}
```

My **app.module.ts** code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WebService } from './web.service';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,  MessagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpModule, NoopAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, MatCardModule, MatSnackBarModule, MatToolbarModule, MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [WebService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am learning Angular from Lynda.com video tutorial. I follow each and every step. but I got the error.

Comment: Mark my answer if it helped, you do not have a good history of marking answers ;)

Comment: You should install the rxjs-compat library as well for other operators that may be needed when moving into rxjs6+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `HttpModule` which is **deprecated** you should use **[`HttpClientModule`](https://angular.io/guide/http)** instead

it's recommended to use **[`Observables over promises`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable)**. By converting to a promise you will lose the ability to cancel a request and the ability to chain RxJS operators.
Before you can use the `HttpClient`, you need to import the Angular `HttpClientModule` into root Module.

```
    import { NgModule }         from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
      ],
//.......
```

**Modified Code:**

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';    

    export class WebService{
        constructor(private httpc:Http){}
        getMessages():Observable<any>{
            return this.httpc.get("http://localhost:2000/messages"); 
        }
    }
```

> Regarding the error you are getting

*As of rxjs 5.5.0-beta.5+ the `toPromise` method is now a permanent method of `Observable`. You don't need to import it anymore **[`Reference`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#550-beta5-2017-10-06)***


Since You are working with RXJS 6+ I would Recommend you to go through the **[`Changes`](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)**
**[`LIVE DEMO WITH HTTPCLIENT`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbe9jg)**

Answer (score 20):

Comment line : import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Comment: funny, but this is correct answer... Solved my case. This is just because toPromise is a legitimate member, no import required now...
the description in answer could be more detailed though...

Comment: Wasn't `.toPromise()` a legitimate member before ... and then not one ... and now it is again?... But before all that, not one -- and before *that* a legitimate one? I feel like every release on that repo changes this.

Answer (score 2):

After Angular 6 you will need to install the rxjs-compat package

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

more information look https://academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/