# IONIC v3 Getting CoinMArketCap API Data

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-httpclient

I want to display the list of all the crypto coins available in market with the help of ionic.

I have used coinmarketcap api for this. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

I have referred this tutorial -> https://www.djamware.com/post/59924f9080aca768e4d2b12e/ionic-3-consuming-rest-api-using-new-angular-43-httpclient

The problem that i am facing is that i am not able to list all the coins. I am able to retrieve the data from api but i guess there is problem in displaying the data.

**Data returned by api**

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "Bitcoin", 
            "symbol": "BTC", 
            "website_slug": "bitcoin"
        }, 
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Litecoin", 
            "symbol": "LTC", 
            "website_slug": "litecoin"
        }, 
        ...
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": 1525137187, 
        "num_cryptocurrencies": 1602, 
        "error": null
    }
]
```

**Error Occurred**

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. (MarketPage.html 18)

```
at NgForOf.ngOnChanges (VM5532 vendor.js:45147)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (VM5532 vendor.js:12781)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (VM5532 vendor.js:14309)
at checkAndUpdateNode (VM5532 vendor.js:14252)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (VM5532 vendor.js:15145)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (VM5532 vendor.js:15086)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (VM5623 MarketPage.ngfactory.js:56)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (VM5532 vendor.js:15071)
at checkAndUpdateView (VM5532 vendor.js:14218)
at callViewAction (VM5532 vendor.js:14569)
```

**Rest.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

apiUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2'; 

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
}

getAllCoinsListing() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/listings').subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
}
}
```

**Market.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-market',
  templateUrl: 'market.html'
})
export class MarketPage {

  marketData: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: 
           RestProvider) {
          this.getAllCoinsListing();
  }

  getAllCoinsListing() {
     this.restProvider.getAllCoinsListing()
     .then(data => {
      this.marketData = data;
     });
  }

}
```

**MarketPage.html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list inset>
         <ion-item *ngFor="let data of marketData">
             <h2>{{data.name}}</h2>
             <p>{{data.name}}</p>
         </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Comment: change ```marketData: any;``` to ```marketData: any[];``` and change ```this.marketData = data.data;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's recommended to use **[`Observables over promises`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable)**. By converting to a promise you will lose the ability to cancel a request and the ability to chain `RxJS`operators.

**Modified code:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

apiUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/'; 

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
}

getAllCoinsListing() {

 return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).map(res=>{return res['data']});//return data of result
}
}
```

**Market.ts**

```
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
        import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

            @Component({
              selector: 'page-market',
              templateUrl: 'market.html'
            })
            export class MarketPage {

              marketData: Array<any>=[];
             //your API returns an array of object

              constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: 
                       RestProvider) {
                      this.getAllCoinsListing();
              }

             getAllCoinsListing() {
           this.restProvider.getAllCoinsListing().
        subscribe(data=>this.marketData=data);

  }

            }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yfjxms)**

Comment: Glad I could help:)