# Confusion regarding basic Rxjs vs Promise usage

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, observable

I know it sounds very basic but I have big confusion about Rxjs specifically when we compare with Promises in order to fetch some data using an API. So here is a quoted defination from some xyz website:

**Promise object may provide only a single value. It can be an array but it’s still a single object. On the contrary, an Observable may emit multiple values over time.**

**Question:**
My question is considering above  defination, if we call an API which returns an array of numbers i.e [1,2,3,4,5], now we use either promise or observable, both will return this array response in first attempt and thats it, so what does it mean when we say **Observable may emit multiple values over time**?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471489/angular-6-observable-explanation-in-plain-english

Comment: @martin thanks alot for sharing that answer, that was the best explanation and got my confusion fixed.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag yes it does.

Comment: I marked it as duplicate. To refer the people in the header of this question to the answer. Don't know why it poster this comment above and didn't link it :/

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says.

[Promise](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)

Emits **one** value or errors.

[Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)
*Anatomy of an Observable*

Emits **multiple** values over time. It stops emitting when:

- The observable **completes**
- The observable **errors**

**Regarding your API**

Does your api `complete` the observable after one value is emitted automatically?

- `yes` it behaves the same like a promise.
- `no` you have to self manage the completion, or your code will always expect your api to receive more values in the future.

**Complete**

You can use the [take](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/take) or [first](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/first) operator for one single emit and complete:

```
observable$.pipe(
  take(1)
)
```

Just consider this comparison to differentiate between the two operators: [take vs first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345969/take1-vs-first)

Comment: Thanks alot @Jonathan it really clearifies most of my confusions. One more question, how is it possible to receive any more response from an API in future? please guide or am i missing some thing?

Answer (score 0):

@martin shared me this answer [Angular 6 - Observable explanation in plain English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52471489/angular-6-observable-explanation-in-plain-english) and that was best one and got my confusion resolved too regarding in what API based scenarios we need to implement Observables and when promises.

Answer (score -1):

Promises returns only a single value(group) hence if you want to return a group of records over time like promises will give you all at once while observables will call return them one at a time in an array format

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the explanation