# Are promises more efficient than observables?

Tags: angular, observable, es6-promise, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I've been learning about promises and observables recently. I found a lot of good information about the feature differences, but **I was wondering if there were any performance / efficiency implications between promises and observables?**

Note: I also looked through this post: [Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable) but I didn't see any mention about efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any performance differences, they're just different paradigms for returning data as Promises return once but Observables return data like a stream.

Comment: Hey Joshin, thanks for the response. I didn't notice any real difference either when playing with test code, but I also couldn't find a way to isolate the method call from the async data. Do you have any reference or is it more so personal experience?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this post](https://medium.com/@mpodlasin/promises-vs-observables-4c123c51fe13)? It explains the *differences* pretty well.

You should look at it from a standpoint of --> "***what's the best for my situation***" rather than --> "***which is more efficient***".

Because they are both equally efficient depending on how you implement them.

Determine what is best depending on your use case. The end of this [article](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/callbacks-vs-promises-vs-rxjs-vs-async-awaits/) in the "Which Approach Should You Use?" sums it up pretty well.

(example: if you are working with angular 2+ I would argue that for "efficiency" in that case would be observables, if not just to make your life easier);

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for the reply. I understand the differences in how they work and why you might pick one; my question is asking specifically about efficiency in the sense of time to execute code. I can't find anything about efficiency anywhere (maybe it's irrelevant?)

Comment: No Problem! I actually did quite a bit of searching yesterday and I could not find anything but I'll keep looking. Currently, I am trying to optimize an angular app as much as possible so its great to consider all performance implications.