# What do we mean by the statement that Observales return more than one value and Promises return only one value in Angular 2?

Tags: angular2-services, angular-promise, angular2-observables

I am relatively new to Angular 2. I was learning the concepts of Promises and Observables. Everywhere it is mentioned that Observables emit more than one value or stream of data while Promises emit a single value. It might be a naive question but can someone please explain what does this mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise vs Observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable for more details on them. Or check this https://medium.com/@mpodlasin/promises-vs-observables-4c123c51fe13 or this: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-observables-http-separating-services-components/