# Angular counterpart of C# Tasks

Tags: c#, typescript, promise, observable

Hello coming from c#  i am struggling a bit to understand which is what when it comes to `typescript`.

So a `Promise` in `Typescript` would be the equivalent of a `C#` `Task` and while in `C#` i unwrap it using `await` in the latter i acess the data inside the context with `subscribe` ?

What is the relationship between `Promise` and `Observable`.
So far i understood that `Observable` class behaves like the one in `System.Reactive` but where does `Promise` come in this equation?

Why do i  have the `toPromise` extension method defined for an `Observable`? I am trying to do a parallel with `C#` and you can't convert an `IEnumerable/IObservable` to a `Task`.

How does that even make sense?I have a stream .Why would i `await` it?There might be no ending to that stream.I would understand if you `await` an element of the `Observable` but why on the whole?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/promise-vs-observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise` and `Observable` are the same only with respect them both being tools for modeling `async` operations.

Their main difference is that `Observable` operates on stream of events, thus it has array-like operators while, on the other hand, `Promise` is an one time stop when it comes to `async` operations > once `async` operation finishes (or fails), your `Promise` is done and cannot be used anymore.

Comment: So basically `Observable` is the same as in `C#` meaning that you can indeed `replay`,`map` ,`fold` , combine streams etc, `subscribe` ..etc ,derived from `IEnumerable` while `Promise` is a typical `Task` that can be run `sync` or `async` ,and the construct `then` is `ContinueWith` equivalent.Am i right?