# How to handle nested calls in $.Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am handling multiple nested calls by using jQuery's `$.Deferred` function. Currently the code is not working properly. I want to fire a function when all requests are done. but currently after two requests it reaches the `console.log`.

```js
function ajac(){
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var api = require('modules/api');
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
      api.request("GET","https://t25501-s39032.sandbox.mozu.com/events/priceadjustment").then(function(res) {
          api.request("GET","https://t25501-s39032.sandbox.mozu.com/events/priceadjustment").then(function(res) {
            dfd.resolve();
          });
      });
  }
  return dfd.promise();
}
$.when(ajac()).then(function(){
  console.log("reached");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are ultimately defining, resolving and returning a *single* deferred, even though your loop indicates that you are intending to track multiple deferreds. `$.when` expects multiple deferreds to be passed as individual arguments. In order for the example to work, I included a mock `asyncEvent` function pulled from the jQuery documentation. See the below snippet to see everything working as expected:

```js
function asyncEvent() {
  var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
 
  // Resolve after a random interval
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
  }, Math.floor( 400 + Math.random() * 2000 ) );
   
  // Return the Promise so caller can't change the Deferred
  return dfd.promise();
}

function makeAjac(i) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred()
    asyncEvent().then(function(res) {
        asyncEvent().then(function(res) {
          console.log(`request pair ${i} complete.`);
          dfd.resolve();
        });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

function ajac() {
  var promisesArray = [];
  for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    promisesArray.push(makeAjac(i));
  }
  return promisesArray;
}

$.when.apply($, ajac()).then(function(){
  console.log("reached");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What we've done here is pull the code that was executing inside your `for` loop into its own function `makeAjac` which returns the promise for its particular iteration through the loop.  In the original `ajac` then we push those returned promises into our `promisesArray`, which we in turn return from `ajac`.  Finally, we leverage [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in order to pass the promises in the array as separate arguments to `$.when`.  As you can see from running the snippet, this functions as expected.

Comment: @DavidBray - That certainly may be true-- I was simply trying to answer the user's specific question regarding the jQuery deferred object. Given the frequent use of `var` and this being a jQuery-specific question, it is possible the OP is in a scenario in which they need to support browsers older browsers that [don't support Promises, like IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score -1):

A single promise can be resolved or rejected only once. You need to return different promises to have all the promises resolved. Something like this:

```
function ajac(){
  var allPromises = [];
  var api = require('modules/api');
  for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
      let dfd = $.Deferred();
      api.request("GET","https://t25501-s39032.sandbox.mozu.com/events/priceadjustment").then(function(res) {
          api.request("GET","https://t25501-s39032.sandbox.mozu.com/events/priceadjustment").then(function(res) {
            dfd.resolve();
          });
      });
      allPromises.push(dfd.promise());
  }
  return Promise.all(allPromises);
}
$.when(ajac()).then(function(){
  console.log("reached");
})
```

A better way to do this would be to use Observables (Example: RxJS)

You can refer to this answer to understand the diffference between pomises and observables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365955/6080889

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't _believe_ the above snippet will work.  Because a _single_ deferred is used for both iterations through the loop (`dfd`), both promises in the `allPromises` array will never reach a "resolved" state and thus the `Promise.all` will not resolve.  I could be wrong, but I tried pulling this into a snippet with some modified mock async functions and that appeared to be the case.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks for pointing that out. It was a scope issue using `var`. I have updated my answer to initialize `dfd` using `let`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

You need to go through with this link: [Using Multiple Deferred Promises - JavaScript/jQuery](https://coderwall.com/p/_eokfg/using-multiple-deferred-promises-javascript-jquery)

```
var callAPI=function(){
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var api = require('modules/api');
         resolve(api.request("GET","https://t25501-s39032.sandbox.mozu.com/events/priceadjustment"));
  });
return promise;
}    


function getInfo(){
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var allPromise=[];
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
                  allPromises.push(callAPI());
            }
                  return Promise.all(allPromises);
     });
return promise;
}

getInfo().then((result)=>{
       console.log("reached",result);
});
```

Comment: `let prom+i = $.Deferred();` this is not valid syntax- JS variable names cannot be dynamically altered/generated in this way outside of using some global namespace hack (ie defining them as properties on the `window` object).

Comment: Hi@AlexanderNied  Edited

Comment: Hi Shubham-- unfortunately this code still has some issues.  The main one I see is that you are returning the `Promise.all` the first time you go through the loop, so it will never iterate.

Comment: Ohhh ;) @AlexanderNied, It is by mistake. Thanks