# Difference between RxJs async operations and javascript promise or async await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

This might be the silly one but help me out with the question. I started learning RxJs but I could see RxJs is used for reactive programming where we can subscribe to events and handling multiple events and process in chaining with observables and I got the doubt like what will be the difference between using async/await or promises in javascript because they are also doing the async flow in javascript. Any advantages over async/await.

Comment: http://reactivex.io/intro.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you search the web a bit as this will give you a much better answer and views on [the difference between asynchronous promise and observable objects](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/javascript-theory-promise-vs-observable-d3087bc1239a)

The main difference is that you use promise when you want the code to be done asynchronously and you use observables when you want to be notify when a variable value is being altered (you observe the variable by subscribing to its events)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference: `Promise` is one-time while `Observable` is assumed to emit for multiple times.

Events, HTTP streams, interval timers - that all does not fit `Promise` well. So `Observable` is more like generators than `Promise`.

Say we need throttling click with requesting server having some short timeout in case server does not respond in 5 seconds. We can either use event handler wrapped into `throttle` and then running Promise-based `fetch` with attaching *promisified* timeout with `Promise.race()`.

Or we can use only `rxjs` to describe complete flow as set of operators.