# Angularfire error: "Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'."

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

When I fetch data from database, it shows this error:

> "Property `subscribe` does not exist on type `Promise<any>`."

How can I solve this error?

This is my code:

```
getUsers(){
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.afs.collection('/users').snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(snapshots => {
        resolve(snapshots)
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md). You are performing a method which does not immediately finish running, so you have to wait for the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that elsewhere in your code, you are trying to subscribe to the promise that getUsers() returns. Unlike Observables, Promises cannot be subscribed to. More on that here: [What is the difference between Promises and Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables)

I don't know the overall goal of your Angular code, but I believe you should be able to get away with:

```
getUsers(){
    return this.afs.collection('/users'.snapshotChanges()
}
```

As this returns an Observable, which you can then subscribe to (or use `async` to synchronize your displayed data to your database).