# How to synchronically call methods after another method in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, synchronous

I have to call some methods synchronically in `ngOnInit()` method, but all of them make some asynchronous calls to an API from the inside. Some variables are setted in the first method, and the second and the third methods need these variables to be already setted. I can't use rxjs mapping operators (mergeMap, switchMap, concatMap, exhaustMap) since the calls are made from separated methods that make other operations.

This is what I have:

```
public taskTypes: any; // variable to be setted in first method
public firstDataSource: any;
public secondDataSource: any;
// some other variables to be setted in first method

constructor(...) {
  this.taskTypes = [];
  this.firstDataSource = [];
  this.secondDataSource = [];
  // some other initializations
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getTaskTypes();
  this.methodOne();
  this.methodTwo()
}

public getTaskTypes(): void {
  this.http.get("url").subscribe(
    (res) => {
      this.taskTypes = res.tasks;
      // some other operations with response data
      // and set other variables
    },
    (err) => {}
  );
  // some other operations with variables
}

public methodOne(): void {
  if (this.taskTypes.length > 0) {
    this.http.get("url/" + 1).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.firstDataSource = res.data;
      },
      (err) => {}
    );
  }
  // some other operations with variables
}

public methodTwo(): void {
  if (this.taskTypes.length > 0) {
    this.http.get("url/" + 2).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.secondDataSource = res.data;
      },
      (err) => {}
    );
  }
  // some other operations with variables
}
```

My problem is that with the call of `ngOnInit()`, all inner methods are called at the same time and the result of the condition: `this.taskTypes.length > 0` is always `false` because the variable `taskTypes` has not been setted by the time when `methodOne()` and `methodTwo()` are called, so `firstDataSource` and `secondDataSource` never get setted with the respective calls to the API. That's why I need `methodOne()` and `methodTwo()` to be called synchronously after `getTaskTypes()`.

Comment: this just looks like poorly structured code. why can't whatever `getTasksTypes()` or `methodOne()` etc doing besides the http call be separated out into other functions that get called independently.  when youre working with asynchronous functions, structuring your functions correctly is essential to maintaining a good code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change your methods to return observable only e.g

```
public getTaskTypes():Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get("url");
}
```

Then use `concat` to execute them sequentially, and `toArray()` to convert result to an array

```
 concat(this.getTaskTypes(),this.methodOne(),this.methodTwo())
 .pipe(toArray()).subscribe(res=>console.log(res))
```

res will contain all results in a array in execution order.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but what about the other operations that are made in the methods? The methods call other services, show some alerts...

Comment: you can chain it to each individual method using pipe() and other operators. e.g 
this.getTaskTypes().pipe(tap(_=>alert("hello")))

Comment: I couldn't accomplish all what I wanted to do, but this serves the purpose of synchronous calls

Answer (score 1):

Of course you CAN do that with rxjs

```
this.http.get("url").pipe(
    map(res => res.tasks),
    filter(taskTypes => taskTypes.length > 0),
    switchMap(taskTypes => combineLatest([this.http.get("url/" + 1), this.http.get("url/" + 2)])),
  ).subscribe(
   ([methodOneResult, methodTwoResult]) => console.log(methodOneResult, methodTwoResult),
  );
```

Have an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jevauk

Answer (score -1):

You should use the concept of `Promise` and `Then`, or `async await`. For example, your ngOnInit should be like this:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  await this.getTaskTypes();
  await this.methodOne();
  await this.methodTwo()
}
```

By using `await`, methodOne will wait until getTaskTypes be resolved. But keep that in mind, `await` only works if your function returns a Promise or an Observable. In this case, because your functions do not return anything, await won't work. So, for example getTaskTypes should be like this:

```
public async getTaskTypes(){
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get("url").subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.taskTypes = res.tasks;
        resolve();
        // some other operations with response data
        // and set other variables
      },
      (err) => {
        reject(err);
      }
    );
    // some other operations with variables
  });
}
```

Of course there are better approaches to solve this, but I tried to make you understand the main ideas. You can read more about it in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: _"Should"_ use? `Observables` are perfectly fine to use for this purpose!

Comment: I said "there are better approaches to solve this", but still there is nothing wrong with Promises. You are free to use anything you want. I suggest you to read [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/what-is-the-difference-between-promises-and-observables]

Comment: I beg to disagree. You state that the OP _"Should"_ use something entirely different than what the question is about, and the question doesn't mention the word `Promise` anywhere. The word you are looking for is _"Could"_, not _"Should"_.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-should-and-must/), “Should” is used to denote recommendations, advice, or to talk about what is generally right or wrong within the permissible limits of society.