# Creating a array using multiple https request typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a angular cli project , i have a method that evaluates multiple https request .`

```js
   this.files = this.http.get("assets/L10n/customer.json")
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    } 
     this.files2 = this.http.get("assets/L10n/customer2.json")
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
```

I want to return this.files and this.files2 as an array .Any help is appreciated`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md):

```
let first = this.http.get("assets/L10n/customer.json")
    .map(res => res.json());
let second = this.http.get("assets/L10n/customer2.json")
    .map(res => res.json());

Observable.forkJoin(first, second).subscribe(
    (resultArray) => {
        // `resultArray` is a combined array of first and second results
        console.log(resultArray);
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked .console im getting the value .But when i try to use the value in another method its giving undefined

Comment: instead of console i added  this.result=data .And when i try to print this.result in another method its saying undefined

Comment: Are you accessing `this.data`? Remember these actions are asynchronous. You will get the value only after the HTTP calls are completed -- which are asynchronous.

Comment: OK.So what i have to do

Comment: You can use [`async/await` on the observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190375/how-can-i-await-on-an-rx-observable). Or pass the function where you want the data as callback and execute it inside `subscribe`.

Comment: Can you edit your question with how your code is structured?