# Run a second Observable is first Observable is false

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9

I created the following AuthenticatedGuard in Angular 9:

```
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

      return this.authenticationService.isSignedIn();

      this.authenticationService.signInRedirect({ state: { url: state.url }}).subscribe();

  }

}
```

The method `authenticationService.isSignedIn` returns an `Observable<boolean>` and `authenticationService.signInRedirect()` returns an `Observable<any>`.

The behaviour should be:

If `authenticationService.isSignedIn` is `false` then do:

```
this.authenticationService.signInRedirect({ state: { url: state.url }}).subscribe();
```

Can this be done and still use Observable?

Comment: By returning you exit the function instantly is that what you want? the second line will never run.

Comment: I could subscribe this.authenticationService.isSignedIn() and check if its value is true or false. If true I would return true, if false I would call signInRedirect. My question is: does this make sense? Should I try to return Observable of Boolean instead of Boolean? But if I do not evaluate the value of authenticationService.isSignedIn then how can I redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change guard to :-

```
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

      return this.authenticationService.isSignedIn().pipe(tap((res)=> {
            if(!res) {
              this.authenticationService.signInRedirect({ state: { url: state.url }}).subscribe();
            }
      }));;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34190965/1778465) the `isSignedIn()` call and then do your `signInRedirect()` to redirect like this, we also need to return a `true/false` value.

```js
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
  const isSignedIn = awiat this.authenticationService.isSignedIn().first().toPromise();
  if (!isSignedIn) {
    this.authenticationService.signInRedirect({ state: { url: state.url }}).subscribe();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```