# In Angular How to Run a Loop that hit Back-End one by one

Tags: node.js, angular, for-loop, angular-services, nodejs-express-server

From Angular When I send some parameter to my Node.js Backend that generate a big array
and got some error or timeout issue.

I wanted to send a limited parameter to back end by Loop.

So how to create this Loop that will hit back end -> then get response from back end -> then hit next loop one by one ???

**N.B:** Previously I create a for loop but that hit all together that didn't meet my need.

**My Previous Angular Loop that didn't work well:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.branchList.length ; i++) {
         this.form.get('branch_code').setValue(this.branchList[i].branch_code);
        
        this.salSub = 
          this.payrollService.submitForSalaryProcess(this.form.value, 
                                                    this.cycleList)
            .subscribe((data)=> {
                  if (data['isExecuted'] == false) {       
                    this.commonService.showErrorMsg(data['message']);
                  } else {                     
                      this.salProcessList = data['data'];
                  }
                  this.salSub.unsubscribe();                    
            }
          )                 
      };
```

Comment: You'll have to convert the observable returned from the payrollService into a promise and **await** it. You can see more info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190375/how-can-i-await-on-an-rx-observable