# rxjs-firstValueFrom around a HTTP request, why would you want that?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, nestjs

I have a question about the use of rxjs firstValueFrom function.

Somehwere (in code I had to take over) I see the following constuction:
(This is NodeJS/NestJS code)

```
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

...
  async getAllProjects() {

    const res = await firstValueFrom(
      this.httpService.get(
        'https://endpoint.somerestservice.com',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-Key': 'XXX',
          },
        },
      ),
    );  
  }
```

And I don't understand what the added value is of firstValueFrom in this.

Why not doing it like this and leave out the rxjs-firstValueFrom?

```
  async getAllProjects() {

    const res = await this.httpService.get(
        'https://endpoint.somerestservice.com',
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-API-Key': 'XXX',
          },
        },
    );  
  }
```

And yes, I have read the docs on firstValueFrom.
As I understand it's making an Observable-Stream of the Promise.
Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I guess to get the correct answer you have to ask the one who wrote the code? `firstValueFrom` creates a Promise from an observable, not the other way around. This is kind of opinion based because there can be multiple reasons, but if you are using `httpService.get` and that function returns an Observable, but you only want the first value, then `firstValueFrom` is a simple way to convert it so that you can use `await` on the request rather than subscribing. Note that you can't use await on an observable, so I'm not sure your second example works correct if I understand the code correctly.

Answer (score 4):

*Generally* it comes down to a matter of opinion and comfort with RxJS. By using `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom` the Observable is turned into a Promise that can be `await`ed, which is usually a more familiar API for most devs. Nest will automatically handle if you return an Observable or a Promise, so it makes no difference there. If you're comfortable with the RxJS pipeline and how to mutate and handle Observables you can keep using `.pipe()` and the rxjs operators, otherwise, using `firstValeuFrom` or `lastValueFrom` could be more beneficial just so it works as usual promises do. It really just depends on what you're comfortable with

Answer (score 1):

`await`-ing an `Observable<dto>` will [resolve immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190375/how-can-i-await-on-an-rx-observable), causing:

- the `res` to be an `Observable<dto>` instead of the `dto` itself that is returned from the backend call,
- the next line of code to be executed before you get the result.

With that you either achieve "*fire & forget*" approach or a possible "*pyramid of doom*" if you have long subscribe/callback code.

On the other hand `await`-ing the `Promise<dto>` (returned by `firstValueFrom`) will suspend the execution until the backend call completes, then assigns `res`, then continues the execution in the next line of code.